# This puzzle is driving me #$&@!

Tags: riddle, wordplay

So, I've been given these strange blocks of clues. I've read them end to end but frankly I just can't make head or tail of them! I know I must be missing some kind of connection somewhere. Can't you help me, please? It's driving me insane!

> Block 1:
>   1. Talk to me, I talk back, ask me why, then I lie.
>   2. A fruit we are, like fat but not quite.
>   3. I'm the happiness that's almost miss.
>
> Block 2:
>   1. Like someone on the warpath, just shorter.
>   2. Rude drivers and angry bulls use me quite often.
>   3. Resting against a curve makes one tidy.
>
> Block 3:
>   1. More like a cow than a cow, just scared.
>   2. Rough weather or long road?
>
> Block 4:
>   1. We are shy, but when you're all gone the world is ours.
>   2. Misleading acronym time? Step on it!
>   3. A most costly kind of gate.
>   4. Lay me down if you want to get your way.
>   5. Put me on and do it good, I once got stopped by some big dude.

What is this puzzle trying to tell me?

Comment: each point of each block are different things that form the idea for the block?

Comment: @lois6b: Yep, every line has a standalone "answer".

Comment: Any chance of a hint on how the individual line answers solve a block?

Comment: Is 2.1 **SOLD**?? Sold(ier)

Comment: Afraid not. I imagine the thought process of the veteran solvers here would go: why would OP use such an unusual word like "warpath" in that line? That may be a good starting point, or at least a hint. :)

Comment: There are hints: they are in the introductory text. It isn't just there for flavour, or I would have mentioned that. :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

What it's trying to tell me --

> N U T S

The gimmick:

> Put the answer words of each block "end to end", as it were, by making "some kind of connection"—a crossword-style connection, linking them at common letters. Correctly connecting the answer words will draw out a letter per block, and these put together spell out the four letter puzzle answer.

entries in **BOLD** were found independently by me (even though others got there too)
entries in ***BOLD ITALIC*** were borrowed from someone else (with credit given).

Block 1:

> 1. Talk to me, I talk back, ask me why, then I lie.  ***PHONE*** (@Dan Russell)
>      you talk (in)to your phone and it talks back; phone-why→phony→lie
>  2. A fruit we are, like fat but not quite.  ***PLUMS*** (@stack reader)
>      fat→plump→plum→plums (because "we" is plural)
>  3. I'm the happiness that's almost miss.  **BLISS**
>      bliss is the happiness synonym that rhymes with miss
>
> ```
> P   B
> HL  L
> O U I
> N  MS
> E   S        → "N"
> ```

Block 2:

> 1. Like someone on the warpath, just shorter.  **WRATH**
>      someone on the warpath is mad as heck→wrathful→wrath; also, **w**<del>a</del>**r**<del>p</del>**ath** leaves wrath
>  2. Rude drivers and angry bulls use me quite often.  **HORN**
>      rude drivers honk their horns, angry bulls gore you with 'em.
>  3. Resting against a curve makes one tidy.  ***CLEAN*** (@Thrax)
>      a curve, "C", with "lean" against it, makes clean=tidy
>
> ```
> W  C
> R  L
> A  E
> T  A
> HORN        → "U"
> ```

Block 3:

> 1. More like a cow than a cow, just scared.  **COWER**
>      more cow-like→cow-er→cower, something you do when scared.
>  2. Rough weather or long road?  ***WINDY*** (@Dreagen)
>      rough weather is windy.  long roads can wind around = windy.
>
> ```
> COWER
>   I
>   N
>   D
>   Y          → "T"
> ```

Block 4:

> 1. We are shy, but when you're all gone the world is ours.  ***MEEK*** (@TwoBitOperation)
>      the meek shall inherit the earth
>  2. Misleading acronym time? Step on it!  **MAT**
>      [m]isleading [a]cronym [t]ime → mat
>  3. A most costly kind of gate.  ***TOLL*** (@dcfyj)
>      toll gates cost money to pass; other gates generally don't.
>  4. Lay me down if you want to get your way.  **LAW**
>      lay down the law to make sure people do things your way.
>  5. Put me on and do it good, I once got stopped by some big dude.  **SHOW**
>      per OP, this is about WWE; Big Show's signature move was the "Show Stopper"
>
> ```
>  MEEK
>  A
>  TOLL
>     A
>  SHOW        → "S"
> ```

Comment: 4.4 is correct! I thought that might one of the more obscure ones. :)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that 4.1 is "MEEK"

Comment: Wow. MAT is an awesome answer :)

Comment: This answer is well on the way to being accepted, but it would be great if you could provide explanations for some of the less obvious riddles (e.g. 4.5).

Comment: Awesome answer @Rubio, and great work everyone! It was fun watching you guys solve this, and I hope to make more of such puzzles in the near future. :)

Comment: @Rubio Awesome work! I didn't expect anyone to solve this puzzle. I thought the OP would end up answering the question in the end :)

Comment: As a not native speaker (and not even a speaker generally, just reader and writer) it was a great time to watch you – all of you – solving the puzzle. I didn't even try myself, as not fluent enough. Those bolded words wouldn't even cross my mind, even though I know most of them. Anyway I'd like to expand the solution a bit by pointing out the connection of the answer with the opening sentence in the puzzle's title: *'This puzzle is driving me NUTS.'*

Comment: Yes, we made the "driving me NUTS" observation while solving it (and stack reader included it in his answer below); I forgot to put it in and didn't feel like going back afterwards for yet another edit, especially when it speaks for itself. :)   glad you were entertained vicariously--we had fun solving it too.

Comment: How did you figure out the visual aspect, Rubio? It's a lovely component, @Xenocacia! Signed $\small -$ typewriter-art lover

Comment: We were in a chat room, I was bemoaning the fact that w/o knowing the connection between each block's clues we were reduced to trial and error asking if our latest guesses for the answer words were correct . . . when suddenly it came to me...

Comment: there was no obvious connection between the words, but finding one would be simplest with that block of just two words... and then it struck me.  there was that W in the middle of COWER, and another at the beginning of WINDY ... and put them together at that W, you have both a literal connection, and a letter.  Finding most of an S with what we had for block 5 made it likely, and when my previously discarded guess of "SHOW" for the final word was confirmed, completing that S, that cinched it

Comment: Thank you! Yes, @Rubio really made quite an inspired leap of deduction there, and with minimal help from me aside from repeatedly stressing the clues in the introductory text. :)

Answer (score 8):

Partial answer

> Block 1:
>  1. Talk to me, I talk back, ask me why, then I lie. **PARROT** *OP: nay*
>  2. A fruit we are, like fat but not quite. **PLUM** (Thanks to @stack reader) *OP: almost yay, but note "WE"*
>  3. I'm the happiness that's almost miss. **BLISS** (Thanks to @Abhirath Mahipal) *OP: yay*
>
>  Block 2:
>  1. Like someone on the warpath, just shorter. **READ** (as in "READY (to fight)", but shortened) *OP: nay*
>  2. Rude drivers and angry bulls use me quite often. **HORN** *OP: yay*
>  3. Resting against a curve makes one tidy. **CLEAN** (the curve is "C") *OP: yay*
>
>  Block 3:
>  1. More like a cow than a cow, just scared. **COWER** (Thanks to @M.Oehm) *OP: yay*
>  2. Rough weather or long road? **WINDY** (thanks to @Dreagen) *OP: yay*
>
>  Block 4:
>  1. We are shy, but when you're all gone the world is ours. **WORM** *OP: nay, correct answer already given*
>  2. Misleading acronym time? Step on it! **MAT** (Thanks to @Rubio) *OP: yay*
>  3. A most costly kind of gate. **HELL** *OP: nay, think @DanRussell got this first*
>  4. Lay me down if you want to get your way. **LAW** (as in the idiom "Lay down the law") *OP: yay*
>  5. Put me on and do it good, I once got stopped by some big dude.

Comment: 2.2 is correct, but I'm afraid 3.1 is slightly off. :)

Comment: I guess 3.1 is COWER. (More like cow, ha!)

Comment: @MOehm That's what I think too, but I didn't write it cause felt like stealing his word XD

Comment: 2.3 was edited to make it clear, you're right but the answer is the word in parentheses. Sorry about that.

Comment: @Xenocacia Thanks for invalidating most of my answers! xD (I got "Law" 3 mins before Rubio, which is why he wrote that he got it independently).

Comment: actually i didn't see your answer at all - i just marked everything I got on my own that way, as I'd started solving clues before posting a partial answer and already had gotten a few before seeing other people's answers.  i guess that was supposed to be a harder one, so props to both of us :)

Comment: could 3.2 be WINDY? as in windy weather is quite rough, and a long road could be a long windy road?

Comment: 1.2 could be Bat, like fruit bat

Comment: 4.3 could be a TOLL as well. Those get costly...

Answer (score 5):

A couple additions:

**Block 4:**

> 1. We are shy, but you're all gone the world is ours.  **MEEK** (the meek shall inherit the Earth)
>  3. A most costly kind of gate. **TOLL** (you have to pay at a toll gate)

Comment: two for two, yay!

Comment: +1 good job! We only have 3 to go now. Still sad my Bill gate and golden gate(bridge) didn't work though XD

Comment: @stackreader: 3 to go indeed, but you do realise that solving all the one-liners is but the first part? :)

Comment: @Xenocacia Of course lol. But I already got a few clues to how we do the second part, unfortunately it's time for bed and it will probably all be solved when I wake up XD

Comment: Okay, hope you get back in time for it then!

Answer (score 4):

Answers in bold only are my own

> The answer is NUTS. as in "driving me nuts!"
>  Good team work everyone!
>
> Block 1:
> 1. Talk to me, I talk back, ask me why, then I lie. **PHONE**(CONFIRMED)
> 2. A fruit we are, like fat but not quite.**PLUMS**(CONFIRMED)
> 3. I'm the happiness that's almost miss. bliss(CONFIRMED)
>
> Block 2:
> 1. Like someone on the warpath, just shorter. wrath(CONFIRMED)
> 2. Rude drivers and angry bulls use me quite often. horn(CONFIRMED)
> 3. Resting against a curve makes me tidy. clean(CONFIRMED)
>
> Block 3:
> 1. More like a cow than a cow, just scared. **COWER**(CONFIRMED)
> 2. Rough weather or long road?windy(CONFIRMED)
>
> Block 4:
> 1. We are shy, but you're all gone the world is ours. meek(CONFIRMED)
> 2. Misleading acronym time? Step on it! mat(CONFIRMED)
> 3. A most costly kind of gate. toll(CONFIRMED)
> 4. Lay me down if you want to get your way. law(CONFIRMED)
> 5. Put me on and do it good, I once got stopped by some big dude.show(CONFIRMED)

I wrote all we got so far in a easy to read format and added all the clues from the question I judged useful to finding the answer.

HINTS

> read them end to end
> can't make head or tail of them
> missing some kind of connection

1

> PHONE
> PLUMS
> BLISS

2

> WRATH
> HORN
> CLEAN

3

> COWER
> WINDY

4

> MEEK
> MAT
> TOLL
> LAW
> SHOW

Comment: Afraid that's rather off-track, there.

Comment: 2.1 needs slightly more thinking. How would you describe a person "on the warpath"?

Comment: for 4.4 I'm not sure if I should... >.>

Comment: Man, it only just occurred to me it could be taken that way. Thanks for the chuckles, have an upvote. :)

Comment: For 4.3 I was thinking Water. Bill definitely works though.

Comment: Sorry, its a costly kind, not a wealthy kind. :p 4.3 is wrong.

Comment: @Xenocacia how do you like my new gate? Hardly gets any costlier :P

Comment: @stackreader: you might want to take the clue a little more literally, or it could cost you. ;) and I lol-ed at your answer to 1.1. You must not have a very good opinion of teenagers, huh?

Comment: @Xenocacia definitely got one this time!

Comment: @stackreader 2.2 looks like the right answer to me too, nice one!

Comment: is there some chat room i'm missing where these confirmations are being made?

Comment: @Rubio I think OP is editing people's post to write if good or not.

Comment: hopefully he gives mine some love. hehe

Comment: @Rubio: there ya go! Good attempts all round, really. :D

Answer (score 3):

Partial Answer. Will keep updating as I get more.

> Block 1:
>  1. Talk to me, I talk back, ask me why, then I lie.
>  2. A fruit we are, like fat but not quite. **PLUM**(from the word Plump)
>  3. I'm the happiness that's almost miss.  **BLISS**
>
>  Block 2:
>  1. Like someone on the warpath, just shorter.
>  2. Rude drivers and angry bulls use me quite often.
>  3. Resting against a curve makes me tidy.
>
>  Block 3:
>  1. More like a cow than a cow, just scared.
>  2. Rough weather or long road?
>
>  Block 4:
>  1. We are shy, but you're all gone the world is ours.**CHILDREN**
>  2. Misleading acronym time? Step on it!
>  3. A most costly kind of gate. **BORDER**
>  4. Lay me down if you want to get your way.  **ROAD**
>  5. Put me on and do it good, I once got stopped by some big dude.

General Idea:-

> Are you talking about children and their safety? (wrong)

Comment: 1.3 is correct, 4.1 and 4.4 are incorrect. Keep trying!

Comment: What about the general idea?

Comment: Completely off, sorry. :x

Comment: I think part 4.1 could be **ROACHES**.

Comment: That's good!  Welcome to Puzzling SE!

Comment: Nice try, but afraid not. Do think a little more literally!

Comment: @rarpm It's Meek :) Somebody already answered it.