# Cryptic Rebuses Continued

Tags: knowledge, rebus, cryptic-clues

Let me remind you, in case you haven’t read my [previous puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47383/cryptic-rebuses), that a cryptic rebus is a rebus that has the form of a [cryptic clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide/45985#45985). That is to say, there are two parts to a cryptic rebus:

- a **definition** of the answer
- a **subsidiary indicator** of the answer.

A definition can take the form of a picture which straightforwardly represents the answer, or it can be a synonym of the answer.

The subsidiary indicator of the answer, on the other hand, will be some kind of rebus word/image play which leads to the answer.

Here is an example:

[image]

This clue depicts a horse head beside an eel, as well as a heel. The horse head (H) and eel (EEL) are a rebus for HEEL. The image of the heel constitutes the definition of the clue, and the H + EEL rebus constitutes the subsidiary indicator.

This simple example illustrates the structure of a cryptic rebus.

As with purely verbal cryptic clues, however, it will not always be clear what constitutes the definition and what constitutes the subsidiary indicator. The definition of a cryptic rebus can appear anywhere (even misleadingly integrated in or around the subsidiary indicator). Part of the fun of these puzzles is the thrill the solver gets upon discovering where exactly to “split” the clue into its components.

Also like purely verbal cryptic clues, there is an exception to the rule that all clues consist of a definition and a subsidiary indicator. So-called double (or triple) rebuses comprise multiple rebuses, each one of which might yield a definition which points to the answer (as in standard cryptic double definitions); alternatively, one (or two) might yield a definition while the other directly yields the answer.

Lastly, rebuses can utilize *any* standard cryptic conventions. They can, for example, signal reversals or beheadings (as in the hose head example, above). They can also make use of abbreviations.

Answers should indicate the solution, the definition, and the path to the solution. An answer to the above heel example would look something like:

> **HEEL** (H[horse head] + EEL; [def] high-heeled shoe)

Now that you’re all caught up, have at 'em:

[image]

<sub>*I don't own any of the images from which I drew in making these puzzles. Where possible I tried to use public domain images. I believe I may be using the rest in accordance with fair use.</sub>

Comment: Your toaster appears to have a problem. Good luck making toast.

Comment: Will you provide the length of each solution?

Comment: @Matt I didn't provide the length in my two previous puzzles ([here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47383/cryptic-rebuses?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [here](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47431/cryptic-rebuses-at-the-zoo)) and people managed to solve them. I won't add lengths (at least not yet), for fear of making them too easy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I've been able to come up with:

1.

> **NET** (01 = 10 backwards; [def] net)

2.*-Thanks to **Matt** for solving this one!*

> **BEAR** (BARE[minimalist (adj.)] in the auditorium; [def] black or brown, for example)

3.

> **T.S. ELIOT** (anagram of TOILETS; [def] author of a poem entitled *The Waste Land*)

4.*-Thanks to **Neil W** and **Volatility** (in chat) for  insights into this one!*

> **BOUILLON** ([def] stock; BULLION [gold ingots[AU in GOTS]] and BOOLEAN[binary] within the ears)

5.

> **ROTATES** (anagram of TOASTER; [def] whirls)

6.*-Thanks to **Neil W** for solving this one!*

> **PENROSE TRIANGLE** (***PEN*** + GOT (Game Of Thrones) UP = ***ROSE*** + ***TRY*** (synonym of ESSAY) + ***ANGLE*** (mixed angel); [def] optical illusion)

Comment: Regarding 1, I'm not sure where you got "neutrality" from. Given the structure of this puzzle type (i.e. cryptic rebuses), they will *all* contain two sides which "depict the same thing". Regarding your answer to 2, you don't seem to identify a definition... 4 is incorrect.

Comment: I removed 'neutrality' from #1. I overthought that one. I included a definition for #2. Will have to give #4 some more thought.

Comment: 2 is still incorrect: the definition must appear *in the clue*. That said, the clue has already been solved, fortuitously, by another puzzler, but there is a more straightforward path to that solution, if you want to search for it.

Comment: I updated to Matt's answer (with perhaps a more straightforward path). So now I just need to figure out #4?

Comment: Nice try, but anagrams must be indicated in some way. It seems to me like you're trying to treat these too much like rebuses and not enough like cryptic clues. 2 contains a fairly obvious indicator for a certain clue type, but it's certainly not anagram.

Comment: Well, you said the clue had already been solved. You are conceding that 'BEAR' is the answer to #2, correct?

Comment: Re 5 - An anagram is a broken word (I assume that's the bit in the clue which determines that the answer is an anagram)

Comment: Yes, BEAR is the answer.

Comment: Re 2 - I'm wondering whether it is something to do with how people are told to think about the audience when they are speaking (and another 4-letter anagram of "BEAR").  But I can't work out what the anagram hint would be.

Comment: Well yes, 'bare' is a synonym of 'minimal' (nice catch) but the OP has already indicated that #2 does not use an anagram.

Comment: Regarding #4, do the actual contents of the binary message (something to do with 'nice try, but this is a dead end') matter?

Comment: Audience is often used to cue homonyms.

Comment: Haha I didn't know that. Makes sense. It's a homonym AND an anagram.

Comment: I switched the 'sounds like' for #2 to 'BARE' - that seems like a simpler path to the solution and doesn't require more specific knowledge of a particular painter. Besides, how do we know that 'BAER' even sounds like 'BEAR'? Thanks Neil W for help with #4 and #6.

Comment: You basically have it. The binary is also between the ears and needs to be accounted for in the solution. Also, you should explain where in the clue is the literal definition of "bouillon".

Comment: OK how does that look? :)

Answer (score 4):

I've got something:

1.

> **NET** (backwards ten) (picture definition)

2.

> **BEAR** ("Baer" (a minimalist) to an audience) (black or brown examples)

3.

> **VETO(e?)S** (anagram of STOVE) (nixes definition)

5.

> **ROTATES** (anagram of toaster) (whirls definition)

Comment: There was an error in clue 3, so I changed it to one that's fair. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 4):

Okay number 6 is...

> PEN + game of thrones (got) up (ROSE) + essay (TRY) + mixed angel (ANGLE) = PENROSE TRIANGLE = optical illusion

And number 4 is something like...

> Taking @Chris Cudmore's GOAUTS = gold (Au) in gots = gold ingots, gold ingots are known as bullion, and bullion *tugs ear* sounds like bouillon, which is a stock, not quite. So the binary ascii code claims to be a dead end, as @wildBillMunson has commented, and a type of dead end is a court. And court-bouillon is a stock, not quite. It's a base for a stock, and binary is a base. So there you almost have it? COURT-BOUILLON? And a spare ear for good luck.

Comment: I like that a whole lot more than what I came up with! Is it okay if I edit my answer for #6 to include yours, or should I leave what I have? Not sure of the proper etiquette.

Comment: Me neither really. As long as you acknowledge the source it seems to be okay based on what I've seen  - and that's fine with me. It seemed largely solved already so I couldn't be bothered doing the full answer myself.

Comment: I changed my answer to yours for #6. Thanks!!!!

Comment: Wow that's an impressive path you took on #4! :)

Comment: Very nice try! You noticed something that others have failed to notice so far. But I take "bouillon" to be synonymous with "stock" (at least "cryptic crossword synonymous").

Comment: So I've overcooked it? It's just bouillon?

Comment: Ding ding ding!

Comment: I updated my answer. Although it's not my answer anymore - it's a group effort to be sure! @NeilW really came through with the heavy lifting!

Answer (score 3):

4. Partial - rebus only

   > GOLD  INGOTS  (using AU as gold)