# Cryptic Rebuses Hit the Books

Tags: knowledge, rebus, cryptic-clues, literature

In order to learn more about Emily Dickinson and T. S. Eliot, who made cameos [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47383/cryptic-rebuses) and [here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47487/cryptic-rebuses-continued?noredirect=1&lq=1), cryptic rebuses are going to the library.

*If you're unsure how cryptic rebuses work, you may want to check out [this primer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZ1MhkSaiHIWWJaYWs1bGY2Q0U/view).*

*Because these sets are usually answered collectively, I will post a community wiki answer that anyone can add to, but feel free to post your own partial solutions.*

[image]

<sub>*I don't own any of the images from which I drew in making these puzzles. Where possible I tried to use public domain images. I believe I may be using the rest in accordance with fair use.</sub>

---

P.S. I hope these puzzles inspire you to read more. At the very least, check out [this poem](http://poetry.byjp.me/poems/l(a). After all, it's a rebus of sorts.

Comment: The clicked image is zoomable.

Comment: Can you put the roman numerals from 12 in a comment?  Still can't read it.

Comment: MCLVMXXIX, apparently

Comment: 12 reads "Composed MCLVMXXIX improperly or properly"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*This is a community wiki answer that anyone can add to.*

1.

> **LOOK UP** ([def] Use a dictionary to discover the meaning of; LOOK printed UPwards)  **[@Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47729/30633)**

2.

> **SCARLET LETTER** ([def] stigma; SCARLET(t)[Johannson] + LETTER[character])  **[@Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47729/30633)**
>    (see addt'l notes by [**@Neil W**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12226/neil-w))

3.

> **TOKEN** ([def] perfunctory; *The Lord of the Rings* without L and I = Tolkein without L and I = Token)  **[@Piotr Pytlik](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47730/30633)**

4.

> **ADDENDUM** ([def] back bit; ADD[sum] + END + UM[backwards $\large\text{μ}$]) - **[@Neil W](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47731/30633)**

5.

> ***THE ALEPH*** ([def] $\Large{א}$; [ddef] "The Aleph," a short story by Argentinian author Jorge Luis Borges in which the titular "Aleph" is a point in space that contains all other points)  (thanks [**@karobar**](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/17825/karobar))
>  Serendipitously, the Brazilian novel *Aleph* invokes the same concept of the Aleph.  **[@Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47729/30633)**

6.

> ***A SERIES OF UNFORTUNATE EVENTS*** ([def] Kids books by L[emony] S[nicket] (né D[aniel] H[andler]); the 3 titles do, indeed, represent a series of unfortunate events)  **[@Ria](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47733/30633)**

7.

> ***THE THEATRE AND ITS DOUBLE***, by Antonin Artaud  ([def] essay collection that inspired a movement; THE THEATRE x2)  **[@Rubio](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47729/30633)**

8.

> ***EXERCISES IN STYLE***, by Raymond Queneau ([def] What the head of the Oulipo movement (Queneau) does to stay fit; EXERCISES[PUSH-up, PULL-up, SIT-up] in STYLE)  **[@Neil W](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12226/neil-w)** & **[@ChrisCudmore](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2752/chris-cudmore)**

9

> **GOGOL** ([def] designer of *Arabesques* (a book); Googl(e)[mostly]*[grotesque])  **[@user2390246](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20466/user2390246)**

10.

> ***THE MAN WITHOUT QUALITIES*** ([def] (image); a novel by Modernist author Robert Musil, whose character, assuming he does lack all qualities, defies description)  **[@Neil W](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12226/neil-w)**

11

> ***THE CASTLE*** - Franz Kafka ([def] 0-0 (chess notation for castling); Kafka died before finishing the novel, hence the unfinished name)  **[@user2390246](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/20466/user2390246)**

12.

> **ORWELL** ([double rebus] Composed "MCLVMXXIX improperly" = wrote MCMLXXXIV (1984); OR + WELL[properly] = Orwell)  **[@Neil W](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12226/neil-w)**

13.

> **COGITO ERGO SUM** ([def] What's certain; COGITO[*I think*, for Cicero] + ERGO[so] + SUM[+]).
>  Descartes declared this (trans: *I think therefore I am*) as the only thing one can be certain of—the fact that one is thinking proves with absolute certainty that one exists).  **[@ChrisCudmore](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2752/chris-cudmore)**

Answer (score 11):

9

> Gogol. Def = "designer of arabesques". Anagram of Googl (Google mostly)

11

> The Castle, by Franz Kafka. Def = 0-0 (chess notation for castling). KAF = Kafka, unfinished. Kafka died before finishing the novel.

Comment: Well done on these!

Comment: Wow! Well done.

Comment: Well done! I knew it was Kafka, but couldn't get my head around the half name..

Comment: really good job.

Comment: Thanks all. I think it's interesting that these two were left to last - I would have really struggled on some of the others. Lots of good solving done by others to get the rest!

Answer (score 7):

1.

> **LOOK UP** ([def] Use a dictionary...of; K O O L, read UPwards)

2.

> **SCARLET LETTER** ([def] stigma; Johannson=Scarlet; character=letter)

5.

> **THE ALEPH** ([def] $\Large{א}$; [ddef] *The Aleph* (a short story by Argentinian author Jorge Luis Borges), in which the titular "Aleph" is a point in space that contains all other points)  (thanks @karobar)
>  Also, the Brazilian novel *Aleph* which has the same concept of the Aleph.

7.

> ***THE THEATRE AND ITS DOUBLE***  ([def] essay collection...movement; "the theater" + its double)

Comment: I would think that the aleph clue may instead refer to "The Aleph" by Jorge Luis Borges, an Argentine.

Comment: @karobar I think that would defeat the point of "the point".

Comment: @Rubio, karobar is correct. I think you just misidentified the country of origin and the type of work (it's a short story, not a novel). Your quoted description about "the point that contains the universe" is correct—it's from the story.

Comment: Interesting. I was referencing ***[Aleph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_(novel))*** which is a novel, by a Brazilian author, and has the line I quoted.  I think you serendipitously have a clue that has two solutions :)  Borges' short story came first (and no doubt was the inspiration) so I'll update

Answer (score 5):

**6)**

> A Series of Unfortunate Events ([def] books that all have title of unfortunate events and a book series by Lemony Snicket (real name Daniel Handler))

Answer (score 4):

1.

> **LOOK UP** ([def] Use a dictionary to discover the meaning of; LOOK wrtten UPwards)

2.

> **SCARLET LETTER** ([def] stigma (A red 'A' is worn to shame an adultress in The Scarlet Letter, novel by Hawthorne); SCARLET(T) Johannson + character = LETTER)

3.

> **TOKEN** ([def] perfunctory (as in effort); No L or I in "The Lord of the Rings", remove L and I from Tolkein)

4.

> **ADDENDUM** ([def] back bit; sum = ADD + END + backwards mu (UM))

6.

> **A SERIES OF UNFORTUNATE EVENTS** ([def] Books by Lemony Snicket (aka Daniel Handler); A Death in the Family, Death of a Salesman, The Plague (literally that))

8.

> **WORKS OUT IN STYLE** ([def] Oulipo is a literary movement where texts were to be written in a constrained style; push- pull- sit- up to keep fit (a work out) in 'style')

10.

> **THE MAN WITHOUT QUALITIES** ([def] Modernist Novel by Musil = Man who defies description)

12.

> **ORWELL** ([def] Composed "MCLVMXXIX properly" = Wrote MCMLXXXIV = 1984; OR + properly (WELL) = Orwell)

Comment: I came to that conclusion on 12 as well, but it just doesn't seem satisfying to me.

Comment: No I can't see the link. Thought someone else might.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I think it is rational, it is a mix of valid and invalid notation as the phrase implies.

Comment: d'oh it's obvious!

Comment: Well.  ***that*** works ... hehe

Comment: Ooh.  I like that.

Comment: BTW I've made some improvements to the explanations of some of yours (and others') answers in the Community Wiki.

Comment: @Rubio not a problem

Comment: @randal'thor my cccc: Throwable party for one time protector of Englishmen (6,3) on iPad not logged into chat.

Comment: @Rubio can you post ^ in chat please?

Comment: @Rubio it's right - hardly worth the trouble really :)

Answer (score 3):

3. > Token ([def] something that is done as an indication or a pledge; "The lord of the Rings" without the letters I and L. Written by Tolkien, removing I and L gives Token)

Answer (score 3):

8.

> **EXERCISE DE STYLE** def: Work By  Raymond Queneau , head of the OLIPOU movement.  To Stay fit cues exercise,  and Style is hidden in the gibberish.  But it still needs work. see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oulipo

13.

> **COGITO ERGO SUM** ("I Think" for Cicero - Cogito) + (so) + SUM (Visual Rebus).  I Think therefore I am -Descartes - Meaning that the only thing that is certain is what he perceives in his own head.