# Cryptic Rebuses Go Meta

Tags: knowledge, rebus, cryptic-clues

At the [library](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47727/cryptic-rebuses-hit-the-books), cryptic rebuses read a book on self-reference.

*If you're unsure how cryptic rebuses work, you may want to check out [this primer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZ1MhkSaiHIWWJaYWs1bGY2Q0U/view).*
[image]

*I don't own any of the images from which I drew in making [these puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48154/cryptic-rebuses-go-meta). Where possible I tried to use public domain images. I believe I may be using the rest in accordance with fair use.

Comment: ^vote already for the tastefully depicted fractal

Comment: @humn, hilarious edit

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1 (found by Ankoganit):

> paradox = "rap" backwards + ado + X

2 (found by M Oehm, conjectural but probably right):

> symbols = cymbals heard, "heard" being clued by a *herd*

3:

> play within a play (note: this device is in fact used in both the specific plays appearing in the rebus)

4:

> rebus = (rex-x) + "sub" backwards (a sub is an under-water vehicle)

5 (found by Neil W):

> nest = N + E + S + first letter of "to"

6:

> Droste phenomenon ("droste" = "sorted" sorted)

7:

> braid = br/aid.

8:

> knot = k + "not" backwards (because 2000 lbs = a ton)

9:

> breaking the fourth wall

Perhaps 10 might be

> just "square" (because the number displayed is a square, and it is displayed within a square box)?

11 (found by Ankoganit):

> M C Escher (MC + anag of "cheers")

12 (found by Ankoganit):

> strange loop (anag of "poor tangles")

Comment: 11 is probably M C Escher (MC=announcer, cheers wildly(anag.)=Escher).

Comment: Ah, yes. I thought the picture looked familiar. Do you want to make your own answer, or shall I start editing other people's suggestions into mine and possible communitiwikify it?

Comment: Feel free to edit (I don't feel like writing up an answer write now xD) :)

Comment: Aha, 1 is PAR( rap=knock<)+ADO(fuss)+X(10)

Comment: (and please please don't CW just because of me, I'll feel forever guilty of depriving you of rep)

Comment: Dammit, I was heading in that direction (but much slower than you). Thanks!

Comment: I'm not exactly starving for rep :-).

Comment: 12 is Strange loop (anag. of poor tangles ; odd+noose)

Comment: @Ankoganit Um, What's the anagram indicator there?

Comment: @Sid The first 'poor'.

Comment: 10 may be something to do with "IM SQUARE" as 999=IM and, well, the box is indeed square

Comment: @Rubio, Gareth is correct in his answer to 10; the intended answer was just "square"...

Comment: So they are "Cymbals he(a)rd" and the definition is the symbols in the bottom row?

Comment: Um, maybe. That doesn't seem to me like the sort of phrase that ought to be the answer to a puzzle, though (it's like, I dunno, "boys went" or "book bought" or "green dustjacket"), and its only meta-ness would be that the clue happens to have symbols in it. So I'm hoping for something more compelling.

Comment: (Not that I can think of anything better, it seems.)

Comment: Oh, I thought that the solution would be "symbols" and the wordplay/rebus "cymbals heard". Maybe the metaness lies in the homophone indicator being homophonic as well.

Comment: Oh, I see. That makes a good deal more sense (and if I'd read your earlier comment with more care I wouldn't have misunderstood; sorry). It's probably right. I'm not terribly keen on the iterated homophone construction, but that's a matter of taste. (No! it's a matter of hearing!)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan 5: N(orth) E(ast) S(outh) T(o)-start = NEST = home

Comment: Ooo. That's probably right. I suppose the connection with the theme is that recursion is kinda like nesting (as in e.g. the nested squares in the Droste panel). Thanks!

Comment: Good job! For what it's worth, the intended wordplay of 2 was "CYMBALS *OVER* HE(a)RD".