# Are there any ways to make a good Cryptic rebus?

Tags: rebus, cryptic-clues, puzzle-creation

How do I make a good **["Cryptic rebus"](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47383/cryptic-rebuses)**?

It's a cryptic **REBUS**, not a text clue.

Comment: It's a cryptic __REBUS__ not a text clue.

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta

Comment: @William Pennanti : No, It's about a kind of puzzle, not the puzzlilng website.

Comment: It's about a kind of puzzle. Not meta. I want to make a good "CRYPTIC" "REBUS".

Comment: Question asked TWO YEARS ago and answered 12 days ago!!!

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is the process that I would recommend:

1. Come up with a phrase or commonly used word.
2. PICTURES. Pictures are an easy way to represent a phrase/word. Another way to come up with the definition part of the cryptic is to use a very vague definition/synonym/whatever that correlates with the definition and incorporate that into the rebus in some way that gives a hint towards the final answer.
3. Just do whatever for the wordplay part! Using prepositions are easy if present in the phrase or in a word in the phrase (e.g. the preposition "on" in "bony"). For a clue like "bony", you could incorporate a B on top of a Y to make B+ON+Y. For the definition, just add like a few bones on the sides. This might not be the best example, however, as it should really be more creative and harder than that.