# Cryptic Rebuses Visit the Art Museum

Tags: knowledge, rebus, cryptic-clues

Before we get to the art, we first have to go over museum etiquette.

A *cryptic rebus* is a rebus that has the form of a [cryptic clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide/45985#45985). That is to say, there are two parts to a cryptic rebus:

- a **definition** of the answer
- a **subsidiary indicator** of the answer.

A definition can take the form of a picture which straightforwardly represents the answer, or it can be a synonym of the answer.

The subsidiary indicator of the answer, on the other hand, will be some kind of rebus word/image play which leads to the answer.

Here is an example:

[image]

This clue depicts a pen beside a sill, both above the word *draw*. The pen and sill are a rebus for PENCIL, which, when taken as a verb, is a synonym of *draw*. The word *draw* constitutes the definition of the clue, and the PEN + SILL rebus constitutes the subsidiary indicator.

This simple example illustrates the structure of a cryptic rebus.

Just like with purely verbal cryptic clues, however, it will not always be clear what constitutes the definition and what constitutes the subsidiary indicator. The definition of a cryptic rebus can appear anywhere (even misleadingly integrated in or around the subsidiary indicator). Part of the fun of these puzzles is the thrill the solver gets upon discovering where exactly to “split” the clue into its components.

Also like purely verbal cryptic clues, there is an exception to the rule that all clues consist of a definition and a subsidiary indicator. So-called double (or triple) rebuses comprise multiple rebuses, all of which, when solved, unequivocally signal the answer.

Lastly, rebuses can utilize any standard cryptic conventions. They can signal containment, reversals, beheadings, anagrams, and homophones. They can also make use of abbreviations.

Answers should indicate the solution, the definition, and the path to the solution. An answer to the above example would look something like:

> **PENCIL** ([def] draw; PEN + SILL)

Now that you’re all caught up, let’s visit the museum. Please do not destroy the art in frustration:

[image]

<sub>*I don't own any of the images from which I drew in making these puzzles. Where possible I tried to use public domain images. I believe I may be using the rest in accordance with fair use.</sub>

Comment: By the way, all of these clues involve art or art-related terms in some way, but the answers are not necessarily thematically related.

Comment: Also, of course, answers may be multiple words.

Comment: Aaaaaaaaaah-ha!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the canonical answer, with attributions (feel free to correct the record):

1.

> **THE LAST SUPPER** ([def] Leo's mural; last supper[dinner]) [@BeastlyGerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil)

2.

> **THE THINKER** (thin ker[cur]; [def] Rodin masterpiece)  [@BeastlyGerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil)

3.

> **DALI** ([def] surreal artist; DA[y] + LI[ne]) [@ChrisCudmore](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2752/chris-cudmore)

4.

> **RUDER** (scrambled DURER; [def] more impolite) [@DylanCristy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11775/dylan-cristy)

5.

> **HANS HOLBEIN THE YOUNGER** ([def] Renaissance man; HANS HOLBE IN (the) YOUNGER) [@ChrisCudmore](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2752/chris-cudmore)

6.

> **RUBENS** ([def] Peter Paul; RUBE GOLDBERG MACHINE - GOLD[AU]+BERG+(MACH in E) = RUBE + [trai]N + S[nake]) [@Roger](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4518/roger) [@DylanCristy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11775/dylan-cristy)

7.

> **NOT A PIPE** ([def] [what Magritte painted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images); KNOT + A + PIPE) [@ChrisCudmore](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2752/chris-cudmore)

8.

> **VAN EYCK** ([def] Flemish primitive; VAN + [Blak]E + [Kandinsk]Y + C[laude Monet] + [O]K[eeffe]) [@Roger](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4518/roger)

9.

> **AMERICAN GOTHIC** ([def] Wood work; AMERICAN[of the USA] in Gothic font) [@IanMacDonald](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10399/ian-macdonald)

10.

> **MIXED MEDIA** ([def] composed of different materials; MADIE is MEDIA mixed up) [@BeastlyGerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/18250/beastly-gerbil) and [@Roger](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4518/roger)

11.

> **[SFUMATO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sfumato)** (S[hredding] F[ruits] and U[rchin] + (to)MATO; [def] blend) [@YowE3K](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/27290/yowe3k)

12.

> **[PIETA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet%C3%A0)** ([ap]P + 8 + A; [def] sculpture) [@NeilW](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12226/neil-w)

13.

> **URINAL** (UR[RU<] IN AL[abama]; [def] font for a Mutt = Fountain according to Mutt—Duchamp's sculpture [Fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_(Duchamp)) consisted of a urinal signed R. Mutt) [@DylanChristy](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11775/dylan-cristy)

Answer (score 6):

My first crack at 12 (completely wrong)

> COLON. A sculpture after append VIII would be the append IX, the appendix is part of the colon and a [Colon statue](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_statue) is a type of African wooden sculpture.

My second crack:

> Ap**p**end = p, + VIII (8) + a = [Pietà](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piet%C3%A0_(Michelangelo)) by Michelangelo.

Comment: If that's not correct, it will be an amazing coincidence!

Comment: My gut tells me (geddit?) the first bit is right, but the rest feels 'too obscure'.

Comment: I would have thought the answer I came up with for #11 was just as obscure, but has been confirmed as being correct.

Comment: I'm with Neil: I think the step towards Append IX is good, but we are probably looking for something that comes before the appendix - be it in a book or in the digiestive system.

Comment: @MOehm - yeah - that sounds plausible - time for more thinking

Comment: *Colon* was not what I had in mind. I've added a hint.

Comment: Given the Bonehead hint, this must be it, although I find the homophone /jeˈt/ versus /eɪt/ a bit hard to swallow. Nice misdirection overall, though.

Comment: "App End" -> P. Cool +1

Answer (score 4):

1. is

> THE LAST SUPPER by Leonardo da Vinci (Leo). It's the last dinner in the line.

2. is

> THINKER - it's a thin cur and a statue by Rodin

3. is

> DALI DALI - (Thanks @ChrisCudmore) Dali DAyLIne

4. is

> DURER - (Thanks @DylanCristy) more impolite = ruder anagram of DURER. It's his self-portrait rearranged - anagram indicator

5. is

> (Well done @ChrisCudmore!) HANS HOLBEN THE YOUNGER - HANSHOLBEN In YOUNGER, renaissance man

6. is

> RUBENS - (Thanks Roger and DylanCristy) - RUBE GOLDBERG MACHINE - (GOLD BERG + MACH IN E) = RUBE. + N (train terminal) + S (snake head) = RUBENS

7. is

> NOT A PIPE - Magritte painting and a knot a pipe.

8. is

> Van Eyck (Thanks @Roger) Van + blakE + kandinskY + Claude + o'Keefe

9. is

> AMERICAN GOTHIC - font and Grant Wood's work (Thanks @IanMacDonald)

10. is

> MIXED MEDIA - anagram of madie gives media and means composed of different materials

11. is

> SFUMATO - (Really well done @YowE3K) **s**hredding **f**ruit and **u**rchins. to**mato**. Means blend

12. is something to do with

> APPENDATE - XIII on append gives appendeight or appendate. Doen't seem to be anything though.

13. is

> FOUNTAIN - UR backwards in AL (alabama) gives URAL. @DylanChristly worked out fountain is a bit like font and the sculpture was done by Duchamp who signed it R. Mutt.

Comment: @Silenus so 'media' is wrong?

Comment: @Silenus ah got it

Comment: [@Roger](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/47545/31484) got 10

Comment: Ah I was close! :P

Comment: You should make this a community wiki. You have only solved #1 and #2 yourself first.

Comment: @IanMacDonald actually I got quite a few more than that and made a lot of progress towards others...

Comment: Other than #1 and #2, the only two you haven't credited are #7 and #9, both of which were solved prior to your edits. Even if you solved #7 and #9 on your own, I'd hardly consider 2 to be "quite a few more".

Comment: @IanMacDonald I was talking about URAL in chat well before, had media, just didn't get 'mixed', actually solved not a pipe independently (and thanks for pointing out I haven't credited 9) and I've been helping in chat with the rest. I count that.

Comment: Looks like @roger beat me by 4 minutes on 6. Credit him.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore done

Answer (score 4):

3.

> **DALI** DA (endless day) + LI (Line without [any sound = ne])

5.

> **HANS HOLBEIN THE YOUNGER** HANS HOLBE IN (THE) YOU NGER. - Renaissance Artist

6.

> **RUBENS** RUBE GOLDBERG MACHINE - [(GOLD BERG) + (MACH IN E) - thanks @DylanCristy ] + N (train terminal) + S (Head off Snake - Thanks @Khale_Kitha ).  Peter Paul signature in part 1 is the definition.

7.

> kNOT A PIPE - Magritte painting - "ceci n'est pas une pipe"

Comment: If REUBEN SNAKE is the answer, where is the definition? Also, I wouldn't include someone *that* obscure in my puzzle!

Comment: Nobody is obscure on google.

Comment: Looks like @roger beat me by 4 minutes on 6. Credit him

Answer (score 4):

11.

> Sfumato 
> Start of Shredding Fruits and Urchin (i.e. SFU)
> then add portion of tomato (i.e. mato)
> Definition = blend (Sfumato = the technique of allowing tones and colors to shade gradually into one another, producing softened outlines or hazy forms.)

Comment: Well done! A few puzzlers were working together on this one and they couldn't crack it. Only 12 remains.

Comment: @Silenus - that one only took me about a minute - once I got the first three letters I just googled - google auto-completed the rest

Answer (score 3):

9.

> American Gothic (Grant Wood's work; written in Gothic font)

13.

> Something about a urinal (RU backwards in AL)

Answer (score 3):

4.

> "More impolite" is *ruder*, which when rearranged is *Durer*, and the image is Albrecht Durer's self-portrait...rearranged.

Some notes on #6 (not a complete answer)

> First we start with a [RUBE GOLDBERG MACHINE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rube_Goldberg_machine), but then we subtract GOLD and BERG and MACHINE (Ernst W.J. Enzel **[MACH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ernst_Mach) in "E"**)

which leaves us with just:

> RUBE + train terminal + viper/bite/fang?

13.

> "[Fountain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fountain_(Duchamp))" by Duchamp. "Fountain" is a urinal (thanks @BeastlyGerbil for the start - UR in AL!), which could be considered a "font" (water receptacle), and Duchamp signed the piece "R. Mutt".

Comment: Well done on 13!

Comment: Nicely done on 13.

Answer (score 3):

6.

> RUBENS -- (RUBE GOLDBERG MACHINE - GOLDBERG MACHINE [thanks @Dylan Cristy] + N [train's terminal letter] + S [snake head]; the picture is signed "Peter Paul" as in Peter Paul Rubens)

8.

> Van Eyck -- (picture of van + blakE, kandinskY, Claude, and o'Keefe)

10.

> Mixed media -- (madie is media mixed up, mixed media means composed of different materials)

Comment: Nice job, especially on 10!

Comment: Nice one on 6, I had a feeling it was going towards that or towards "___esque", since that's a recognized art term (because of his style).