# Shining holder - What am I?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, cryptic-clues

> I am a shining holder of the preservatives of life, with a hilt of
>   melded grey matter of the core and matter of the body, black as night.
>   Flames can touch me but they can do nothing but heat the blaze inside.
>
> If somebody uses me to come to your aid, you will find things made
>   easier for you. In days that have passed, I was known as an embrace.
>
> One has had the experience every day, that when the sun has just
>   passed over our heads, his head goes underwater, and his world starts
>   spinning round and round; he feels like he’s aflame.
>
> Another of my kind is *the chart of a chaotic battle, where we lost*
>   *Tallanvor.*
>
> Another is *the start of dawn ending, so every ruler treads for an arid*
>   *wasteland.*

What am I?

Hint 1:

> My head is curved.

Comment: You may want to check [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide) before using cryptic clue tag.

Comment: Are you sure that [cryptic-clues] is an appropriate tag here?

Comment: @Deusovi, yes, it is not all cryptic, but there are a few cryptics embeded within...

Comment: Given the wording here and judging by your comments on the first answer, it appears all but certain that [tag:cryptic-clues] does *NOT* apply.  That tag is not for "cryptically worded clues".  It is for a very specific form (and usually, format) of clue that uses a set of rules to hint at its answer with a definition and a word-play; see the link Techidiot supplied earlier.  Please verify that you understand exactly what is meant by [tag:cryptic-clues] and adjust the tags if needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @Rubio I am 100% sure the answer **does** contain cryptic clues, in a meta-cryptic sort of way. I see that it may be difficult to actually identify the clues, as they are a part of the wider riddle. If this makes things too difficult then I will add a hint later on that identifies where the cryptics are.

Comment: @Rubio The final line does appear to be a cryptic clue, at least. But that's about as far as I've got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect (but am not certain) that the shining holder is:

> A SPOON

Because:
I am a shining holder of the preservatives of life, with a hilt of melded grey matter of the core and matter of the body, black as night. Flames can touch me but they can do nothing but heat the blaze inside.

> The "preservatives of life" means food, which may be held in a spoon when eating. "Grey matter of the core" is iron (from the Earth's core) and black "matter of the body" is carbon, which "meld" into steel, a material spoons may be made from. Fire will not (usually) damage a spoon but will heat the contents.

If somebody uses me to come to your aid, you will find things made easier for you. In days that have passed, I was known as an embrace.

> The first part is unclear, but "spooning" is a form of embrace. **OP Edit:** To spoon feed someone is to make things very easy for them

One has had the experience every day, that when the sun has just passed over our heads, his head goes underwater, and his world starts spinning round and round; he feels like he’s aflame.

> I think this is a convoluted way of following "sun" with "dae" (from "head" without its head, spun around?) to form "sundae", which is a type of spoon. **OP Edit:** Not what I was looking for, this was in reference to a 'teaspoon', they stir tea which is very hot, with their head underwater. This happens every afternoon at 'teatime'.

Another of my kind is the chart of a chaotic battle, where we lost Tallanvor.

> An anagram of "battle", minus a "T" for the lost Tallanvor, is "table", another type of spoon.

Another is the start of dawn ending, so every ruler treads for an arid wasteland.

> The first letters ("start") of "dawn ending, so every ruler treads" form "desert", which must be a spoon for eating sand. It may resemble the more common dessert spoon. :)

Comment: Very impresive, well done!

Comment: @Melkor: D'oh! Can't believe I didn't get the "tea" part. Thanks for the edits, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I think I may have the answer, but am still fuzzy on a couple of the clues.

I believe the shining holder is a

> **COMPASS**

I am a shining holder of the preservatives of living, with a hilt of melded grey matter of the core and matter of the body, black as night. Flames can touch me but they can do nothing but heat the blaze inside.

> The magnetized needle (matter of the core) is suspended in organic liquid, such as lamp oil (preservatives of living). The background of the compass is black as night. Exposure to flame would heat the needle and also the oil it is suspended in.

If somebody uses me to come to your aid, you will find things made easier for you. In days that have passed, I was known as an embrace.

> If you need help with navigation, a compass will make things easier. The word compass used to mean embrace (like the words en*compass* or *compass*ion).

One of my kind is the chart of a chaotic battle, where we lost Tallanvor.

> Martyn Tallanvor was a character in the *Wheel of Time*. I'm not sure what the chart of a chaotic battle refers to.

Another has had the experience every day, that when the sun has just passed over our heads, his head goes underwater, and his world starts spinning round and round; he feels like he’s aflame.

> This is in reference to a sundial compass. When the sun passes overhead, the sundial's shadow passes over itself.

Another is the start of dawn ending, so every ruler treads for an arid wasteland.

> I think this refers to a Qibla compass, which points Muslims to Mecca for their morning (after dawn) prayers. It also points them in the right direction for their annual pilgrimage. Mecca is located in a desert (an arid wasteland).

Comment: Nice explanations. But I am still not sure whats with the cryptic-clues tag. +1

Comment: @Techidiot I'm not sure about that either. ;)

Comment: Good answer but nor what I'm looking for

Comment: Is my answer on the right track, or in some way related to the answer you're looking for? Also, as a general puzzling question, is it a problem when more than one answer can be achieved with as many connections as I presented in my answer?

Comment: @wildBillMunson not really on track, but you are right in that it is a simple commonly used item. You made some good connections however some parts didn't fit very well, like the Tallanvor line, and the first line (how is lamp oil a preservative of living?)

Comment: I bet "melded grey matter of the core and matter of the body, black as night" means iron + carbon = steel.