# Three Blind Mice - rhyming cryptics!

Tags: rhyme, cryptic-clues

Each line of the following poem is a cryptic clue.

> Free blind mice with spirit are bound;
>   Hack tail off, our first glorious inch.
>   Tool is almost fine after quick sound;
>   The mice's tails in the breeze did flinch.

I'll provide the word lengths too, but in a spoilertag in case you want to solve it without them:

> 6, 5, 7, 6.

---

Since the second line has gone unsolved for so long, here's a **hint**:

> ignore punctuation; it's a red herring.

Comment: I got some off-site help from @Deusovi in making this puzzle, so he knows the solution to the third line. The other lines should be fair game to him as well as everyone else.

Comment: And knowing deusovi with cryptics of course he'll get the rest

Comment: Is the second one rot13(cevzr)? I’m probably not understanding how this works properly but it seemed worth asking.

Comment: @Ryan Nope. How did you get that?

Comment: Oh is the second unsolved?

Comment: @Beastly No, Sp3000 solved it in tSL (but refused to post an answer, so Rubio incorporated it in his).

Comment: @randal'thor aah didn't see his edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Actual Solution**

```
Free blind mice with spirit are bound;
```

> Found by a few people independently, originally rejected for a couple of issues, but subsequently confirmed by OP in The Sphinx's Lair - this one is:
>  **CEMENT**   (Free blind mice [(M-iCE)* → CEM] with [+] spirit [ENT] are [=] bound [*def.*])

```
Hack tail off, our first glorious inch.
```

> **COUGH**   (Hack [*def.*]; tail off our [OU_]; first glorious [G]; inch ["in CH" → C(OUG)H])
>  Credit to @Sp3000 in TSL for spotting and solving this, um, Libertarian construction

```
Tool is almost fine after quick sound;
```

> **MACHINE**   (Tool [*def.*]; almost fine [INE]; quick sound [MACH]; after [MACH+INE])

```
The mice's tails in the breeze did flinch.
```

> **[@Beastly Gerbil](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/48844/30633)** already found this one is:
>   **WINCED** - (The mice's tails [_CE]; in the breeze [WIN(CE)D]; did flinch [*def.*])

Comment: Good work! (Why shouldn't "mice's tails" be "ce"?)

Comment: I think he's referring to the ['s]

Comment: Pretty sure the surface reading works just as well without the possessive.

Comment: @Rubio mice's tails = tails of mice = last two letters of "mice".

Comment: Oh. Ok I'll buy that :)

Answer (score 8):

The last is

> Winced

Because

> The tail of mices is 'ce' and a breeze is a wind - so ce in wind gives winced meaning flinched or did flinch. Also 6 letters from the enumeration.

And Rubio got the third

> Machine - Quick sound = Mach after 'almost fine' = ine Tool = def.

Comment: Good job! (For the record, this one I came up only about half an hour ago - the rest of them I've had waiting for weeks while I struggled to come up with a fourth line that would fit nicely.)

Comment: @randal'thor yeah this was definitely easier than the rest, but I still like it :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer for 3 is something like (the word count doens't fit):

> Knife - a tool
>
>  Because almost fine means angram of fine = nife
>
>  The sound of quick is k, because that's what it sounds like
>
>  So "nife" after "k" make "knife"
>
>  Maybe the real answer is a type of Knife?

Original impression for 3 was:

> Thunderbolt

Because

> Bolt = Quick
>  
>  Thunder = Sound
>
>  Bolt = Tool

Comment: 3 has an enumeration of 7 sadly

Comment: Also, you're answer is neither a tool nor a sound.

Comment: @Melkor It is a [word](https://www.google.com/search?num=30&newwindow=1&espv=2&rlz=1C1CHFX_enUS652US652&q=thunderbolt+definition&oq=thunderbolt+definition&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i7i30k1l4j0j0i7i30k1l2j0i5i30k1j0i7i30k1.362950.365213.0.365596.11.11.0.0.0.0.212.1353.0j7j1.8.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..3.8.1349...0i13k1j0i7i5i30k1.UPHA0h-foCM) but I don't think it applies to this cryptic clue.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil, I managed to miss the word lengths

Comment: @Melkor I'm not sure if you're aware, but Cryptic clues have very specific [rules](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide) and [cluing words](http://bestforpuzzles.com/cryptic-crossword-dictionary/)