# This is not a puzzle!

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, rhyme, steganography

> This is not a puzzle!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> There’s nothing to solve here!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> This is not a puzzle!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
>
> Have i made myself clear???????????????????
>
> Let me repeat.....

$$$$

> This IS NOT a puzzle!
>
> Have I MADE MYSELF clear?
>
> This IS NOT a puzzle!
>
> There’s NOTHING to solve here!!1111!!!!111!!1111!!!!!1111!1111!!!1!!

**"Hint":**

> This is not a hint! $\phantom{1}$ 
> In case you were befuddled. $\phantom{represents}$ 
> This is not a hint!  $\phantom{word}$ 
> Because the above is not a puzzle! $\phantom{enumerations}$

Comment: Completely inspired somehow by https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide

Comment: This is not a puzzle? Is it related to puzzle creation or solving? If not we may need to close it as off topic. ;)

Comment: @DqwertyC oops, you got me there

Comment: Just to verify, are you missing an "!" or "1" from the last line?

Comment: @mkinson Not missing them, no

Comment: Just as well that this is not an answer then. This is NOT an answer!!!!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a puzzle. **;-)**

Comment: @Randal'Thor I knew you'd be the one to do that :P First my homework, now this... *shakes head*

Answer (score 22, accepted):

### THE ANSWER:

> **"PUZZLE"**

The solution, first with the upper half:

> Count the punctuation marks at the end of the five sentences in the upper half. You get **13, 15, 18, 19, 5**. These numbers, when attributed to position in the alphabet, give **M, O, R, S, E**.

Now look at the second half:

> The words go from lower case to ALL CAPS and then back again. One might say that it literally looks like how morse code looks, with the short and tiny dots packed together with the higher dashes. Combining that with the punctuation hint at the final line (similar to before) we see that there are 20 1s and 20 !s; and there are 20 words in the second half of the hints. One of them means something, and thanks to a recent edit to the question, we can see that the "1 represents enumerations". So I'll ignore the !s.

So where do we go with this?

> The 1s enumerate this sequence of numbers: **4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1**. If we apply that sequence to represent the length of individual letters in morse code, and use lower case words as dots and upper case words as dashes, we can construct a morse code sequence: **.--. ..- --.. --.. .-.. .**, which translates into **P U Z Z L E**.

---

P.S:

> Thanks to mkinson for jogging my brain into action.

Comment: I can confirm your first part is right, nice job! You're on the right track

Comment: I see your edit... how can I tell which "ones"?

Comment: probably should have worded that better- ones represent the enumeration.

Comment: Ok... and just to be clear, the solution is on the last line, right?

Comment: It appears the lowercase is . and the upper case is -. Gives you a word, which I wont post in comments.

Comment: @mkinson why don't you post it as a separate solution?

Comment: GOT IT (thanks mkinson for jogging my cogs)

Comment: edit coming soon

Comment: Nice, you got it!