# Where will this take me?

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, wordplay, lateral-thinking

Zero zero one. On the monitor, it blinked. I was eager to know what secrets  Mr.Brown was holding. Not very long, he was known as one of the best secret agent. Keeping all the secrets, safe and sound. Saving them as the bargain chip.

But alas, he betrayed the organization, and got killed, leaving all this behind
On the memory card so tiny, and accompanying it with :

> It comes with voice so muffled,
>   and for the kill it waits.
>   Leaving the footprints in eternal time,
>   grabbing your anxiety it celebrates.
>
> It can drown you, oh so deep,
>   with things going horribly wrong.
>   BUT, don't overlook the solution,
>   you are the accomplice all along
>
> Solve this riddle, and get a place it belongs.

Zero zero two. Obviously first part is telling me about the place? It is a place. Not that I doubt Mr.Brown. Key to the information, is it in the card or is it in the place? Something smells fishy for sure.

Zero zero three. On the monitor, it blinked, again. I am not the only one who is trying. Not the only one. Keeping calm, I searched for the hint, and I fount it. Small note hidden (I won't say, where I found it)

> I am the ONLY one standing between ad23dnd anagrammatically. You have to look for the first half of me

---

**note :** I wanted to take the second part out, but after posting it on meta, and due to vague nature of the question itself, I am updating the question here itself. After getting the answer, I will again update the riddle to its next part

Comment: Is the 'You have two look' text intentional?

Comment: Nope, just an autocorrect on my phone.... Corrected it

Comment: What about 'ad23dnd' ??

Comment: That one  is right

Answer (score 3):

Some ideas which might help and a wild guess:

> I am the ONLY one standing between **ad23dnd** anagrammatically.

ad23dnd

> anagrams to '2D and 3D.' The only thing standing between 2D and 3D is **depth.**

This theme is reinforced by the line:

> It can drown you, oh so deep

Next

> You have to *look* for the first half of me

Makes me think of a

> **search**

This, combined with the phrase *first half* leads me to guess that the password is:

> Depth-First-Search

Because

> The first half of the riddle describes 'the depths,' which is also the first half of the answer, while the second paragraph describes a futile 'search.' Also, perhaps a stretch, but a Depth First Search is also a terrible way to guess someone's password (for instance, by guessing 001, then 002, and so on...)

Comment: you are correct about the anagram, but after that, unfortunately you are looking in the wrong direction. I have added "cryptic-clues" tag.

Comment: @smriti Are you *sure* that tag fits? It's not just for "clues of a cryptic nature", it's specifically for clues of the type used in [cryptic crosswords](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide), which are designed with specific features that don't seem to be in evidence here.

Comment: @Rubio so what should I call the tag, that is cryptic(tricky/confusing) and goes with word play? I will add that.

Comment: @smriti probably [tag:enigmatic-puzzle], or maybe one of ([tag:steganography] or  [tag:anagram]) if either one is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer would be

> DREAM

I am the ONLY one standing between ad23dnd anagrammatically.

> Anagrams are 2D and 3D, as @TwoBitOperation described.

It can drown you, oh so deep,
with things going horribly wrong.

> Dreams(Nightmare) can do so.

It comes with voice so muffled,
and for the kill it waits.

> That's right you can't even notice if they are coming.

Leaving the footprints in eternal time,
grabbing your anxiety it celebrates.

> We can't forget nightmares easily and a good dream can make you feel better.

I hope it's convincing enough.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! This is a good start, but it looks a bit tenuous to me. Can you explain how it fits the rest of the riddle?

Comment: @F1Krazy please check updated answer, if it convinces you.

Comment: sorry but not the right answer

Answer (score 0):

Is the password:

> **Depression**?

I am the ONLY one standing between ad23dnd anagrammatically. You have to look for the first half of me

> Anagram is 2D and 3D and depth is the only one standing between it. First half of depth is **DEP**

It comes with voice so muffled,
and for the kill it waits.

> We cannot determine when depression hits

Leaving the footprints in eternal time,
grabbing your anxiety it celebrates.

> It comes in our anxiety moments...

It can drown you, oh so deep,
with things going horribly wrong.

> Old thoughts and memories will haunt you...

BUT, don't overlook the solution,
you are the accomplice all along

> Depression is within us and can only be resolved by us...

Comment: sorry, but not the right answer, enigmatic-puzzle and lateral thinking tags come to play here.