# Big star initially shows gratitude (6)

Tags: cryptic-clues

A cryptic clue I originally wrote in a card to my cryptic crossword sensei:

> Big star initially shows gratitude (6)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A big possibility is:

> THANKS

Explanation:

> Tom Hanks, initially THanks, was the star of the film Big.

Comment: I don't quite follow the wordplay here. Is it (G+unaxf?)(Rot 13)

Comment: Sid, I think as you have above and I suppose (vavgvnyyl whfg npgf ba uvf svefg anzr, ohg fubhyq ba obgu?)(Rot13)

Answer (score 5):

Alternative answer:

> Tyrese (Gibson) - big movie star, initial two letters in his name are an acronym for “thank you”

Comment: Where do you get the RESE part? In a cryptic clue, all the letters need to be covered.

Comment: FYI: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide