# Baring my Heart

Tags: cryptic-clues

<sub>This is an entry into the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge: Restricted title 1](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6352/fortnightly-topic-challenge-35-restricted-title-1)</sub>

Alice has sent a message to Bob. Can you help Bob figure it out?

> Ordinary vehicle turning all
>   Finished challenged
>   Industrious real king after not so easy win
>   Bent nail bone
>   Unfavourable right with small Energy after victory following advantage
>   Manner in the French following Street
>   Knife from Rand in wager
>   Sprint to right point

Comment: But ... I wouldn't gamble my knife.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The encoding of the message is related to...

> the fact that, in each of the cryptic clues, the central letter (heart) is missing from the wordplay.

The clues and their solutions:

> Ordinary vehicle turning all VAN[**I**] + LLA<, thanks to Philip
>  Finished challenged COMP[**L**]ETED
>  Industrious real king after not so easy win HARD+W[**O**]+R+KING, also from Philip
>  Bent nail bone AN[**V**]IL*
>  Unfavourable right with small Energy after victory following advantage AD+V[**E**]+R+S+E
>  Manner in the French following Street ST[**Y**] + LE
>  Knife from Rand in wager B(AY[**O**]N)ET, from TwoBitOperation
>  Sprint to right point R[**U**]+N

The final message is...

> I LOVE YOU

Comment: This is correct. Once you figure out all the clues, I will accept this answer.

Comment: Damn, you beat me for a few of the CCs :-D

Comment: #1 is rot13(inavyyn)

Comment: #3 is (I think) - rot13(uneqjbexvat)

Comment: @Philip: ouch, I tried to think of words ending in yyn, but somehow that didn't come to mind! :)

Comment: #7 might be rot13(onl[b]arg),  but I don't have the full wordplay

Comment: @TwoBitOperation, that was my thought for the definition as well though I didn't see the wordplay until you pointed it out, so thanks!

Comment: Ooh, that's a nice one @TwoBitOperation , it took the parentheses that ffao used for me to see it.

Comment: Even with all the answers, I have no idea what's going on here.

Comment: @LordFarquaad: Are you familiar with [cryptic clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide)? These are cryptic clues, but with the additional twist that the middle letter of each answer, the "heart", has been omitted in the wordplay.