# Appropriate Terms -- Cryptic Clues

Tags: cryptic-clues

> **Step 1 -- Appropriate Terms**

Solve the following cryptic clues:

1. Reportedly talked about revolt (7)
2. Studied super varied education (7)
3. Beginners without faults (7)
4. OB keeps bizarre custom (7)
5. Scarf is sure concealing cleavage (7)
6. Croon at ranch to odd associate  (7)
7. Was left around south (7)
8. Laid back dealer has ecstasy! (7)

> **Step 2 -- Short Term Solutions**

Use step one's answers to fill in this simple crossword. One of these answers is not like the others! Find out which one, and use it to your advantage.

[image]

> **Step 3 --  The Late Term**

Take the 4 marked letters from the puzzle to get the final, somewhat inappropriate, answer.

[image]

(Edit:  This was a late addition to the fortnightly challenge)

Comment: 2 could refer to Jack, as in "Jack of all trades is master of none, but better than the master of 1". 3 I think is a n00b, as they are a beginner without faults.

Comment: @Joe-You-Know Please read [this guide](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide) for further information on Cryptic clues

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Step 1

> 1. DISGUST (def: 'revolt', sounds like 'discussed') 
>  2. PERUSED (def: 'studied', anagram of 'super' + 'ed')
>  3. NOVICES (def: 'beginners', no vices)
>  4. BESPOKE (def: 'custom', anagram of 'OB keeps')
>  5. FISSURE (def: 'cleavage', 'scarF IS SURE')
>  6. CONTACT (def: 'associate', odd letters of 'CrOoN aT rAnCh To')
>  7. EXISTED (def: 'was', 'exited' around 's')
>  8. RELAXED (def: 'laid', 'dealer' backwards has 'x')

Step 2

> All of the words end with a 4-letter word, except EXISTED. Use that as the horizontal word, and fill in the four letter words, using the given 'S' as help:
>
> ```
> S    PU
> U  G OS
> RA U KE 
> EXISTED
>  ECTA
>  DE C
>   S T
> ```

Step 3:

> The selected letters give: **XKCD**.

Comment: ugh, i can't format...

Comment: Exactly right, with incredible speed!  I'll have to try to make the clues harder next time...