# Beginner's Cryptic Crossword

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, crosswords

I've always been terrible at Cryptic Crosswords so I spent some time creating some clues of my own and have managed to fit them together to make a small Crossword of my own.
Once solved, any issues will be duly noted.

[image]

> **ACROSS**
>   1. Cannabis consumes a realisation (6)
>   3. Cross-dress in Canadian province abbreviation (6)
>   4. Greek micro-illness uses telephone (7)
>
> **DOWN**
>   2. Swedish band sings profanity (6)

Comment: This is really hard.

Comment: Unless you specify otherwise, cryptic crossword solvers expect a clue to have a definition, either at the beginning or the end of the clue.
You should also indicate when your wordplay includes a homophone (all but one of your clues do, which is over-using it). Words like broadcast, said, spoken, to audience, are homophone indicators.

Comment: One more technical comment on your grid. More than two unches (spaces that are only in one answer) in a row make the puzzle much harder to solve. Try to avoid that.

Comment: If you're interested, there's a really nice guide [on this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984) for creating these.

Comment: @Jafe thank you for that link, I see what Rupert means now

Comment: That's not a Canadian City.

Comment: huh. that's my bad, always thought it was

Comment: @AHKieran, FWIW I feel the same way about cryptic crosswords. Many moons ago (long before the internet was popularised), I got a book out from the library about how to solve them and even with that in hand, I wasn't able to complete a full crossword. I really enjoyed your take on them in this puzzle, so perhaps rather than aiming to create an exact cryptic crossword, create your own brand of them (like you have with this one), but perhaps don't tag it with cryptic-crosswords (enigmatic-puzzle + crosswords would probably suffice). Great puzzle! :)

Comment: @Dmihawk I think I had Riley Riddles in mind when creating these clues, I'll post another one with some more clues later :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answers are:

1 across

> POTATO
> When pronounced, it sounds like "pot" (cannabis) "ate" (consumes) "oh" (realisation)

3 across

> DRAGON
> "Drag" (cross-dress) + "ON" (abbreviation for Ontario, Canada)

4 across

> MUSICAL
> Like 1 across, sounds like "mu" (Greek symbol used to mean miciro) "sic" (sounds like sick = illness) "call" (uses telephone)

2 down

> ABACUS
> "Aba" (Swedish band is ABBA) + "cus" (to swear/be profane is "to cuss")

Like so

> [image: Solved Crossword]

Answer (score -3):

Looks like your clues aren't [cryptic](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide).
Please read the guide carefully or retag your question "[crosswords](/questions/tagged/crosswords)".
Also, I'm unable to see the grid. Read my profile too.

1. Cannabis consumes a realisation (6)

   > **POTATO** (pot-ate-oh)
   >  Suggestion: Like food (6)
2. Swedish band sings profanity (6)

   > **ABACUS** (Swedish band = ABBA, Profanity= CUSs)
   >  Suggestion: Computer = A scuba at sea (6)
3. Cross-dress in Canadian province abbreviation (6)

   > **DRAGON** (DRAG + ONtario)
   >  Suggestion: Pull on fictional creature (6)
4. Greek micro-illness uses telephone (7)

   > **MUSICAL** (MU + SICk, make telephone CALl)
   >  Suggestion: Litmus, I call some enjoyable (7)*

Comment: According to an article I saw, the word "Potato" can be a verb that means "like".