# Intermediate's Cryptic Crossword

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

My second attempt at making a cryptic crossword using the tips I was given in my [first attempt](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/78755/beginners-cryptic-crossword).

I'm not sure if they adhere exactly to the rules, as there are a couple occurrences of homophones.

Also note that where applicable, the English spelling is used as opposed to American spelling.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Across**

1.

> Century = Cent + U.R.Y.

7.

> Determine = Deter + mine

8.

> Samsung = Sam + sung

11.

> Kingdom = King + d.o.m

12.

> Current = Cur + rent

14.

> Neighbour = Neigh + bo(a)r

15.

> Operate = Opera + ate

**Down**

2.

> Updated = Up+date+ted 
>  **Original interpretation:** Up + d (inner) + a + ted

3.

> Background = Back + ground

4.

> Minimum = Mini + mum

5.

> Adventure = Ad + vent + u + re

6.

> Crossword = Cross + word

9.(Courtesy of JonMark Perry)

> Vauxhall = V + AUX + hall

10.

> Action = Act + ion

13.

> Listener = List + tenor

Comment: how do you figure 2 down?

Comment: Well done! I will give the tick if you can write the method/parts for the ones you haven't already

Comment: @JonMarkPerry I've edited now, the "ballooned house" and "movie with talking bear" parts are obvious enough. I took "dinner and a" to be "d inner and a" = da

Comment: 2 down's splitting isn't quite right, but the last two parts kind of overlap

Comment: I can't get 'ballooned house='up', and dinner=d is a bit weak

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Have you ever seen 'Up', the movie? dinner is "d inner" as in d is inside the word.

Comment: it's actually rot13(onyybbarq ubhfr vf sebz gur cvkne zbivr "Hc" naq "qvaare naq n zbivr" vf zrnag gb or "qngr" gb pbzovar jvgu "grq" gb znxr Hc+qngr+grq = Hcqngrq)

Comment: @AHKieran Ah okay

Answer (score 4):

9 down:

> V+AUX+HALL gives Vauxhall

Comment: Ah, yes, of course +1