# Dress up a ship's surface

Tags: wordplay, knowledge, cryptic-clues

> 1. Boss turns blind eye to knife user (4)
> 2. Charge with first-degree larceny makes sense (4)
> 3. Recite backwards about king computer worm (6)
> 4. Start donning trousers, topless educators (5)
> 5. Initial understanding negotiated, communist backs down (5)
> 6. Boys have top notch territories (5)
> 7. Neo, alternatively! (3)
> 8. Look for turban head by telephone (4)
> 9. Point to uneven axioms (3)
> 10. First groom taken by wife-to-be to game (6)
> 11. Your hearing time long ago (4)
> 12. Spring quest starts before fall ends (5)
> 13. In distress, comedian Louis punches hard (5)
> 14. Warning for ultimate disobedience (4)
> 15. Dress up a ship's surface (4)
> 16. Tetris complicated for caretaker (6)

What are we listing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've arrived rather late to this party, but here are all but one of the answers others haven't already got, along with ones others *have* already got for convenience, credit given by initials. [EDITED to add:] MOehm figured out the last one (#3), which I'm sure I would never have got. So now we have the full list.

> ```
> CHEF    wv        1. Boss turns blind eye to knife user (4)
> FEEL              2. Charge with first-degree larceny makes sense (4)
> DABBER            3. Recite backwards about king computer worm (6)
> DEANS             4. Start donning trousers, topless educators (5)
> UNDER         js  5. Initial understanding negotiated, communist backs down (5)
> LANDS             6. Boys have top notch territories (5)
> ONE        ok     7. Neo, alternatively! (3)
> SEEK          js  8. Look for turban head by telephone (4)
> AIM               9. Point to uneven axioms (3)
> BRIDGE           10. First groom taken by wife-to-be to game (6)
> YORE    wv       11. Your hearing time long ago (4)
> QUELL            12. Spring quest starts before fall ends (5)
> SOCKS         js 13. In distress, comedian Louis punches hard (5)
> FORE    wv       14. Warning for ultimate disobedience (4)
> DECK    wv ok js 15. Dress up a ship's surface (4)
> SITTER  wv    js 16. Tetris complicated for caretaker (6)
> ```

And, to answer the final question, we are listing

> CHEF FEEL D / ABBER DEAN / S UNDER LAND / S ONE SEE / K AIM BRIDGE / YORE Q / UELL S / OCKS FORE D / ECK SITTER

which is to say

> Sheffield, Aberdeen, Sunderland, Swansea, Cambridge, York, Wells, Oxford, Exeter

which are

> British cities

though whether there is some more specific link I haven't yet figured out. [EDITED to add:] In comments, OP says nothing more specific was intended.

Note: an earlier version of this answer said (obviously absurdly) that they were

> *English* cities

because I'm a moron; thanks to the OP for politely pointing out my mistake in the comments.

The table above omits explanations of the cryptic-clue solutions, for the sake of brevity. Here they are:

> ```
> CHEF     1. Boss turns blind eye to knife user (4)                     CHIEF without I
> FEEL     2. Charge with first-degree larceny makes sense (4)           FEE + L(arceny)
> DABBER   3. Recite backwards about king computer worm (6)              READ< around BB
> DEANS    4. Start donning trousers, topless educators (5)              D(onning) + (j)EANS
> UNDER    5. Initial understanding negotiated, communist backs down (5) U(nder...) N(eg...) + RED<
> LANDS    6. Boys have top notch territories (5)                        LADS contains N(otch)
> ONE      7. Neo, alternatively! (3)                                    anag. &lit
> SEEK     8. Look for turban head by telephone (4)                      sounds like SIKH
> AIM      9. Point to uneven axioms (3)                                 AxIoMs (un-even letters)
> BRIDGE  10. First groom taken by wife-to-be to game (6)                G(room) in BRIDE
> YORE    11. Your hearing time long ago (4)                             sounds like YOUR
> QUELL   12. Spring quest starts before fall ends (5)                   QUE(st) + (fa)LL
> SOCKS   13. In distress, comedian Louis punches hard (5)               CK in SOS
> FORE    14. Warning for ultimate disobedience (4)                      FOR + (disobedienc)E
> DECK    15. Dress up a ship's surface (4)                              double def
> SITTER  16. Tetris complicated for caretaker (6)                       anag. of TETRIS
> ```

Relevant not-entirely-universal knowledge:

> 3. There's a singer called B B King. 7. As in *The Matrix*. 8. Sikhs wear turbans. 12. The word QUELL has a (rather obscure) meaning of "spring or fountain". 14. "Fore!" is a warning cry in the game of golf, meaning "look out, fast-moving golf ball heading your way".

Comment: I had just got 6 and 10 but 13 was from js.

Comment: OK, I've un-credited you for that one. Thanks for your honesty :-).

Comment: I guess that 3 is rot13(qnoore).

Comment: Plausible as far as definition goes, but I don't understand the wordplay. What am I missing?

Comment: ... Oh, duh. I see.

Comment: Yes, not your usual king. And not Elvis, either. `:)`

Comment: ah, and now I see how the whole thing works.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, @MOehm, had you spotted the top-level connection when you got #3 or did you do it independently?

Comment: that's clever :) @jafe

Comment: No, I didn't have the top level connection. (I missed 2, which I still can't work out and 12, because I couldn't establish that the word meant what it ought to mean.) I had a vague idea going into the right direction, but was far from the solution. Well done, Gareth and jafe!

Comment: I am pretty sure 12 is right (and have verified that the word does have that meaning; it's in the OED).

Comment: It is possible that *HRYYF* could be *JNYRF* which does have a *havirefvgl* of that name.

Comment: But that would break the rule that all are cities. (But surely Aberdeen and Swansea are not _English_ cities.) Wells is known for being the smallest city by far in England with a cathedral. I don't think that you will have much success trying to punch a hole into this answer ...

Comment: What you have is the intended answer. No other connection than rot13(pvgl fgnghf), at least not intentionally :) Note though that it's GB, not just E.

Comment: @MOehm I was making a suggestion, not punching a hole, since GM found an objection to his own answer.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, jafe and MOehm; I don't know what I was thinking.

Comment: @WeatherVane: My last comment was needlessly harsh and snarky. I apologize.

Comment: Would it be possible to include how you get the word out of each line?

Comment: Done. The explanations may be rather too cryptic if you aren't used to the conventions of cryptic crossword clues; see https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide for more information about that.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan my answer for 6 is wrong, so you can remove my credit. thanks!

Comment: OK, un-credited. I should have looked more closely to begin with :-). Congratulations on your honesty!

Answer (score 4):

Partial solution

> ```
> Chef    1. Boss turns blind eye to knife user (4)
> ```
>
> ```
>         2. Charge with first-degree larceny makes sense (4)
> ```
>
> ```
>         3. Recite backwards about king computer worm (6)
> ```
>
> ```
>         4. Start donning trousers, topless educators (5)
> ```
>
> ```
>         5. Initial understanding negotiated, communist backs down (5)
> ```
>
> ```
> Lands   6. Boys have top notch territories (5)
> ```
>
> ```
>         7. Neo, alternatively! (3)
> ```
>
> ```
>         8. Look for turban head by telephone (4)
> ```
>
> ```
>         9. Point to uneven axioms (3)
> ```
>
> ```
> Bridge  10. First groom taken by wife-to-be to game (6)
> ```
>
> ```
> Yore    11. Your hearing time long ago (4)
> ```
>
> ```
>         12. Spring quest starts before fall ends (5)
> ```
>
> ```
>         13. In distress, comedian Louis punches hard (5)
> ```
>
> ```
> Fore    14. Warning for ultimate disobedience (4)
> ```
>
> ```
> Deck    15. Dress up a ship's surface (4)
> ```
>
> ```
> Sitter  16. Tetris complicated for caretaker (6)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

5. Initial understanding negotiated, communist backs down (5)

> UNDER (Initials of understanding negotiated is UN, communist is RED but backwards is DER, down is under)

8. Look for turban head by telephone (4)

> SEEK (sounds like Sikh, means to look for)

13. In distress, comedian Louis punches hard (5)

> SOCKS  (In SOS, Louis CK is a comedian, socking means punching)

15. Dress up a ship's surface (4)

> DECK (as in Deck the halls, and a ship's deck.)

16. Tetris complicated for caretaker (6)

> SITTER (anagram of tetris, short for babysitter)

Answer (score 2):

Partial:

6: Boys have top notch territories (5)

> **TERRY** (front of territories, boy name)

7: Neo, alternatively! (3)

> **ONE** (anagram of neo)

15: Dress up a ship's surface (4)

> **DECK** (dress up = deck, ship's surface = deck)