# Cryptic Acrostic 1: Off Balance

Tags: cryptic-clues, acrostic

This is an [acrostic puzzle](http://www.puzzazz.com/how-to/acrostics) which uses [cryptic clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide). If you're unfamiliar with either or both of those, click the associated link.

A complete answer should give the quote, author and source, as well as solutions and explanations of the cryptic clues.

Oh, and in case you're too lazy to solve this with actual pencil and paper, I've created an [interactive version](https://codepen.io/juicifer/full/VwzjXjb) that will autofill from the grid to the clues and vice versa. Have fun!

<sub>An accessible version for the visually impaired can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/MQ6exR6p).</sub>

[image: an image of the puzzle. for an interactive or accessible version, visit the link above]

Comment: Would it be possible to provide a transcription of the clues/grid, for visually impaired users? Also please note that the "interactive version" link gives me a "This debug view expired." 403 error.

Comment: thanks for the heads up. I believe I've fixed the link. I had thought/hoped that the link would be accessible since it is all text, but if that's not the case, I can work on a transcription

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It says:

> LOOK AT THE WORLD AROUND YOU. IT MAY SEEM LIKE AN IMMOVABLE, IMPLACABLE PLACE. IT IS NOT. WITH THE SLIGHTEST PUSH IN JUST THE RIGHT PLACE, IT CAN BE TIPPED.

This is from

> Malcolm Gladwell's "The Tipping Point".

Answers and explanations:

> A. GRITTY: initial letters.
>  B. LAVA: LA + VA.
>  C. ASKED OUT: anagram of DATE US OK; &lit.
>  D. DOW JONES: substring.
>  E. WHITTLE: T(wo) L(arge) in WHITE.
>  F. EPAULETS: AU in EP + LETS.
>  G. LUTHER: LUTHIER minus I.
>  H. LIMBO: LIMB + O.
>  I. TRASH: RASH with T "at first".
>  J. ITCHED: I(mage) + anagram of THE CD.
>  K. PATH: substring.
>  L. POPEYE: POPE precedes YE.
>  M. ICICLE: initial letters.
>  N. NABISCO: NO about AB (at bat) + IS + C(onfusing).
>  O. GHENT: GENT eats H(og).
>  P. PALM: double definition.
>  Q. OPTIMAL: TIM in OPAL.
>  R. IN THE MAIL: IN (during) + anagram of HAMLET I.
>  S. NIMBUS: NIM + BUS.
>  T. TIKE: anagram of KITE.

Credit where due:

> I know nothing about sport and Stiv kindly pointed out that AB = at bat.

Comment: Knowing [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_bat) would help with N :)

Comment: Oh. Once again my ignorance of sport proves a problem. Thanks!

Comment: Edited accordingly. Thanks once again.

Comment: yup, that's exactly it! glad that was the only thing in there that didn't make sense, haha

Comment: I would like to add a note that Chris Cudmore solved this thing at about the same time as I did (he actually posted an answer with just the quote while I was writing up my answers, but deleted it when I gently objected). If you like my answer you might want to consider finding something of his and upvoting it.