# Guess the extra rule in this crossword!

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image: Empty crossword grid]

Six "across" clues need to be modified in some way before solving. However, I'm not telling you which ones, or what the required modification is. You'll have to figure it out on your own.

You'll get some help, though. Every "down" clue contains one extra letter, which must be removed before solving. All modifications produce real words found in the UKACD. The removed letters spell out a name I have given to the above-mentioned modification.

**Across**
1. Modest (to the extreme!) expression of consent (6)
6. Jean Sibelius's fourth described by revolutionary intellect (5)
11. Hound caught (8)
15. Interpret computer science units (7)
16. Save wingless animals giving away 1000 pieces of local currency on the islands (7)
18. Trump up the extremely ironic morality (5)
24. Turned red hot (7)
25. "Sleepy" official twisted (5)
26. Comedian Ben Stone's wanting to be less healthy (5)
27. Judy's finally wearing a rather beautiful pyjama (7)
30. Lewis accepted everyone's invitations (5)
32. Wise alien made short written works akin to the oeuvre of Robert Frost (7)
34. Take the life of criminal? Gun on the outside leads to doom (7)
38. Dry wines for Reagan and JFK, say (8)
39. Online community in general needs no backing from router, in principle (5)
40. A cover's turned over (6)

**Down**
2. Fold man undressed standing by side of dark tree (3)
3. Water in Champagne, with a little bit of syrup added in, for moan in scripture (4)
4. Race fled from new Danish province (5)
5. Both sides of tablet provided with a beverage (3)
7. Fourth of rouse, a cardinal direction; back from west (4)
8. Born to be carved from stone, nevermore (3)
9. Event incorporated papers on teen at sea (8)
10. Give the wrong amount of millisiemens or wave the baton call wonky? (10)
12. Feet ion dirt, shoulder baggage and walk? (4)
13. Racing final lost boy sauciest big wild horse on the big screen (10)
14. Prevent seeking supernatural practices (6)
17. None follow this image rushing after leader of orcs (5)
19. Union Fighter Jete in possession of a weapon (8)
20. Second-hand copy of *Harry Pottier and the Sorcerer's Stone* might be so labelled? (4)
21. State inspected a home for the auditor (5)
22. Charge pa fiver? (4)
23. Programmer lardy points to shapes (6)
28. Source of most of the world's opium is brought up to stoop addict group (4)
29. Dandies admit Spielberg essentially making many a film that doves poorly at the box office (5)
31. Knowledge from paste generations is theoretical or experimental content (4)
33. Billy and Indiana stole one from a temple full of tramps (4)
35. Spanish lord put one flower in Russia (3)
36. Operating system university refused to get rind of (3)
37. Ton the way north, immigrant ultimately accepted by group of 27 North American people (3)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The filled grid:

> [image: Filled crossword grid]

Clue explanations:

> [image: clue explanations, with removed letters marked]
>
>  The removed letters spell `FORTUNE COOKIE IMPROVEMENT`, a reference to a common joke where "in bed" is added to the end of a fortune from a fortune cookie -- usually creating an unintended innuendo. Here, the six modified Across clues all need "in bed" added to the end of them to be solved.

Comment: I am really new to the puzzling site. I find the question and your answer really cryptic. It would be nice if you could elaborate a bit on it

Comment: @an4s911 As shown in the tags, this is a [tag:cryptic-crossword] -- a genre of crossword that has some strange, specific rules! I've written [a guide](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide) that explains how the clues work in more detail, and also explains the typical notation (that I've used here for answers).