# Cryptic Acrostic 3: Built So Fly

Tags: cryptic-clues, acrostic

This is an [acrostic puzzle](http://www.puzzazz.com/how-to/acrostics) which uses [cryptic clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide). If you're unfamiliar with either or both of those, click the associated link.

A complete answer should give the quote, author and source, as well as solutions and explanations of the cryptic clues.

Oh, and in case you're too lazy to solve this with actual pencil and paper, I've created an [interactive version](https://codepen.io/juicifer/full/ExvzMRd) that will autofill from the grid to the clues and vice versa. Have fun!

<sub>An accessible version for the visually impaired can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/m1kMXBbS).</sub>

[image: ![an image of the puzzle. for an interactive or accessible version, visit the link above]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solved puzzle spells:

> **I was determined to master the first step of success: failure. For anyone who insists that taking one step forward and two steps backward will never get you anywhere, I protest: It will if you're walking backwards.**; as shown by the first letters of the answers, this is a quote from George **Watsky**'s ***How To Ruin Everything***.

Clue explanations:

> A. `WINTER + GREEN`
>  B. `(-h)AWK + WARD<`
>  C. `TABLOID*`
>  D. `SWIFT (ddef)`
>  E. `_K + ISS`
>  F. `YOYO + MA`
>  G. `HALF-STAFF` (punny def: "standard" is another word for a flag)
>  H. `OSTRICH(-a)*`
>  I. `WEE + PING + WILL + O + W`
>  J. `TWEE + T(-r)Y` ([Tweety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweety) is a bird who pronounces /k/ as /t/, so in his catchphrase he says "tat" instead of "cat")
>  K. not sure - perhaps `O(ATM + IL<)K`, but it then seems like the inserted two parts are clued the wrong way around
>  L. `ROTA(-no<)TED<`
>  M. `U + (a→(bo)P)WARDS` ("top mark" = "first letter")
>  N. `IN PAIRS*`
>  O. `N+E+W+S`
>  P. `ESSEN + C.E.`
>  Q. `V_ I_ + RUS`
>  R. `(th)EF(ts) + FORT`
>  S. `R_ + US + T_ B_ E_ + _L + T (&lit)`
>  T. `Y(E_)ARN`
>  U. `TAKE A SEAT*`
>  V. `HOP(-s) + SCOTCH`
>  W. `(I+O)+DINE` (definition is "Periodically, I")
>  X. `NERD(lihc)<`
>  Y. `G + RUN + _T`

Comment: Very nicely solved Dues :)

Comment: you've pretty much got it, but you're missing the first part of the quote and your explanation for K isn't quite right (though the answer is correct). lmk if you need a hint on that

Comment: I think K is O(ATM)IL + K just for completeness's sake, with OIL = liquid

Comment: @TwoBitOperation that was the intended parsing