# Cryptic Acrostic 4: Follow the Leader

Tags: cryptic-clues, acrostic

This is an [acrostic puzzle](http://www.puzzazz.com/how-to/acrostics) which uses [cryptic clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide). If you're unfamiliar with either or both of those, you can click the associated link.

A complete answer should give the quote, author and source, as well as solutions and explanations of the cryptic clues.

Oh, and in case you're too lazy to solve this with actual pencil and paper, I've created an [interactive version](https://codepen.io/juicifer/full/mdBEOmL) that will autofill from the grid to the clues and vice versa. Have fun!

<sub>An accessible version for the visually impaired can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/NRm9TeuM).</sub>

[image: an image of the puzzle. for an interactive or accessible version, visit the link above]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOURCE**

> Marlantes, *Matterhorn*

**QUOTE**

> Days slid by mercifully without enemy contact. Eventually the artillery battery came in, blasting out gun pits from the clay, digging in bunkers for their fire control center.

**CLUES**

> A. MILITARY = MARY + I [single] + LIT
>  B. ACCORD (ddef.)
>  C. REGULATING = R_E + GULAG + TIN [type of soldier]
>  D. LITTLE WOMEN [Marches, last name of characters] = LIT + WELT< [back-lash] + OMEN
>  E. ACCIDENT = ACCENT + ID
>  F. NIMBLY = LIMB* in NY
>  G. TADPOLE = TAD [bit] + POLE
>  H. EGG YOLK = GO [shot] about GY [thousand yards] embedded in ELK
>  I. STRETCHIER = STRETCHER + I
>  J. MUTINY = MU + TINY
>  K. ALIEN = A + LI + \E \N  (&lit)
>  L. TRUFFLE = mysELF FURTively
>  M. TYRRANY = \T \Y + RAN + NY
>  N. EVENING OUT (ddef.)
>  O. REFUELS =  REFU(-sa+E)LS
>  P. HUBBY = HUB + BY
>  Q. ORBITS [0's] = OR + BITS [1's perhaps]
>  R. RORSCHACH TEST = SHORTS(-top) CATCHER*
>  S. NIFTY = [(-f)IFTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_fifty-dollar_bill) + _N_