# Avoid consuming broken cereal?

Tags: word, knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, visual, letters

Please allow me to lead you on a merry dance through the following original puzzle (for which you will need to work out exactly which way to proceed).

The question is: **What type of dance is it?** The answer is 8 letters long.

[image: Puzzle image]

Comment: Well, I do get the title, so that's a start.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The dance is a

> **NEWS REEL!**

First we notice that

> we have a compass rose with clues at the eight points. The clues are dashes, digits, and stars. All stars are red, some numbers are red.

To the right are four squares.

> Each square tells us something about the clues around the rose.

The first square

> keys that the digits represent the initials of the compass points. 1=N, 2=NE, 3=E, etc...

The second square

> has a symbol for each of the categories. For example, at North is music, to the Northeast is Old World Geography and to the West is New World Geography.

The third square

> Who knows, maybe we don't need it.

The fourth square

> indicates how the clues are ordered: chronologically, alphabetically, by size, or (alphabetically by last name).

For the clues at the compass points

> we first replace each digit by its one- or two-letter abbreviation. We can notice patterns, find some answers, deduce the category and even fill in the answers with no clues where they form a complete set. Then the letters represented by red symbols can be anagrammed to get the name of a letter of the [NATO phonetic alphabet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NATO_phonetic_alphabet).

North

> These are [Nirvana albums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nirvana_discography) in chronological order
>  BLEACH
>  NEVERMIND
>  IN UTERO
>  CHARLIE

Northeast

> These are [New England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_England) states
>  RHODE ISLAND
>  CONNECTICUT
>  NEW HAMPSHIRE
>  VERMONT
>  MASSACHUSETTS
>  MAINE
>  INDIA

East

> These are members of rock band [The Eagles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagles_(band))
>  GLENN FREY
>  DON HENLEY
>  BERNIE LEADON
>  RANDY MEISNER
>  ALFA

Southeast

> These are [Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#oldest) listed in chronological order
>  STACK OVERFLOW
>  SERVER FAULT
>  META STACK EXCHANGE
>  SUPER USER
>  MATHOVERFLOW
>  STACK APPS
>  WEB APPLICATIONS
>  ARQADE
>  WEBMASTERS
>  SEASONED ADVICE
>  ...
>  MIKE

South

> The [five senses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sense)
>  HEARING
>  SIGHT
>  SMELL
>  TASTE
>  TOUCH
>  ECHO

Southwest

> Locations of the [Seven Wonders of the Ancient World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven_Wonders_of_the_Ancient_World)
>  ALEXANDRIA
>  BABYLON
>  EPHESUS
>  GIZA
>  HALICARNASSUS
>  OLYMPIA
>  RHODES
>  LIMA

West

> [Counties of Wales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_counties_of_the_United_Kingdom#Wales)
>  CLWYD
>  DYFED
>  GWENT
>  GWYNEDD
>  MID GLAMORGAN
>  POWYS
>  SOUTH GLAMORGAN
>  WEST GLAMORGAN
>  ALFA

Northwest

> [Nations with nuclear weapons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_states_with_nuclear_weapons) (one assumed)
>  UNITED STATES
>  RUSSIA
>  UNITED KINGDOM
>  FRANCE
>  CHINA
>  INDIA
>  PAKISTAN
>  NORTH KOREA
>  (ISRAEL)
>  DELTA

Now we have our 8 letters

> `CHARLIE (C), INDIA (I), ALPHA (A), MIKE (M), ECHO (E), LIMA (L), ALFA (A), DELTA (D)`

And we didn't even need to understand that third box! All we need to do now is

> take the letters in the order indicated by the red arrows

and we get our answer

> **IAALCEMD!**
>  Hmm, that doesn't seem quite right...

The way to proceed on this merry dance is to notice that

> the third box actually indicates the total number of letters in each of the *intended* category names!

We can figure them out as follows

> NIRVANA (7)
>  NEW ENGLAND (10)
>  EAGLES (5)
>  STACK EXCHANGE (13)
>  SENSES (6)
>  SEVEN WONDERS (12)
>  WALES (5)
>  NUCLEAR WEAPONS (14)
>  As confirmation, each category name's initials are the initials of that cardinal point, ie (North = Nirvana, North East = New England, East = Eagles etc...)

Finally,

> we index into each category name by the corresponding NATO letter to get another eight letters: `R N E E E S W L`. Taking them in the order indicated by the red arrows gives us our dance, the **NEWS REEL**, which is appropriate because NEWS spells the cardinal points and the rose is round like a reel.

The title

> looks like a [cryptic clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide), but as @No Name and @JLee point out, it is merely a rephrasing of ["Never Eat Shredded Wheat"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/never_eat_Shredded_Wheat), a mnemonic for the points of the compass going clockwise.

Comment: Can you include the answer to the cryptic clue on the title as well?

Comment: @justhalf workin on it...

Comment: All looking good @cap :) You can probably skip over the 'red herring' part - it wasn't intended to be one and may be a tad confusing for readers; I think your narrative works fine without it (I really like the 'Hmm' train of thought!). The only thing one *might* describe as a red herring here is the fact that each group contains a distinct total number of items, which may suggest an ordering to some solvers - however, this was more a construction challenge on my part, rather than any kind of solving suggestion. Re the title, think 'mnemonic', and then you've got it all!

Comment: @Stiv rot13(ab rng fcyvg jurng)?

Comment: It's not enough to avoid consuming broken cereal. One must also avoid consuming wet breakfast pastries!