# A cryptic clue: A thing from far away

Tags: cryptic-clues

Here it is:

A thing from far away (Texas, specifically) wraps around and attaches to a weird far gone thing. (9)

Comment: What's the source of this clue?

Comment: This doesn't really follow the rules of cryptic clues for a few different reasons - most notably, an indirect anagram, a not-grammatically-consistent definition, no clear split between definition and wordplay, and *many* unused words. I'd recommend reading my [cryptic clue guide](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide) and practicing on other cryptics before jumping into writing them.

Comment: @Deusovi If I parse it correctly there is no indirect anagram ("far gone" is in the clue and TX is reversed around it). Also there seems to be a clear split: "A thing from far away" is the def and the rest is the wordplay. Only thing I agree with is the number of unused words (although the reversal of TX is also unclear to me unless around is playing double duty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> anagram(TX FAR GONE) = xenograft

Comment: I think this answer can be improved by noting rot13(vafgrnq bs orvat cneg bs nantenz, Grknf [GK] "jencf nebhaq" -> KG naq "nggnpurf gb" -> juvpu xvaqn vzcyvrf vg tbrf nebhaq n "sne tbar" nantenz).