# Something Here is Fishy

Tags: cryptic-clues

This is a cryptic clue I just came up with:

> Fisherman stands behind small rope noose (9)

It's my first ever puzzle, so hopefully it isn't too much of a stretch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best I can come up with is

> <s>ENTANGLER</s> STRANGLER (thanks msh210),

because

> a fisherman is an ANGLER, behind STR (I'm not sure how this means small), and a rope is an STRANGLER because it can strangle people.

Apparently the OP's intention was

> that STR is short for (a "small" version of) STRING (a.k.a. "rope"), but that's an indirect wordplay and leaves no definition part of the clue. See [Cryptic Clue Guide](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/45984/5373) for more detailed info on what proper cryptic clues are "supposed to" look like.

Comment: By the same logic it could be strangler.

Comment: I suppose that works too, and it's very close to the intended answer. Good job

Comment: @TylerSelden Is the intended answer what msh210 said? I can edit if you want.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yep, MSH210 got it. ROT13(Zl guvaxvat jnf gung lbh pna hfr fgevat va cynpr bs ebcr, gura fubegra vg gb fge.)

Comment: Edited my post to include a definition.