# Cryptic Sundays #1

Tags: cryptic-clues

Welcome to our first episode of Cryptic Sundays, a cryptic collection that starts on, well, you know, every Sunday! We have some puzzles to begin, so let's start now!

---

> - Still, there are wild lionesses (9)
> - David hides in comic RO's sanctuaries (5)
> - Ocular, said first person (3)
> - Marx's joke with chicken's direction (6)
> - World's top cartoon company (4)
> - Even shelters scramble, however (12)
> - A heartless Danish gerund is fleeing (7)
> - Oddly, main dorm in fife, by belly (7)

Comment: Is there anything connecting the clues, or are they all separate?

Comment: They are all seperate! :)

Comment: The third clue is ill-formed. The second clue has a poor definition. The fifth clue seems to have an irrelevant word. The next-to-last clue is ill-formed.

Comment: Stop complaining, please! IT WAS INTENTIONALLY MADE TO BE HARD!!!

Comment: There's a difference between "hard" and "unfair" - cryptic clues are expected to abide by certain rules, so solvers can be justifiably upset if it turns out the puzzle they were trying to solve broke those rules. See https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide (note: I have not checked into either side of the argument here, just giving a default hard =/= unfair response)

Comment: Correction: ... IT WAS INTENTIONALLY MADE TO BE UNFAIR!

Comment: If you make puzzles that are deliberately unfair, then people will deliberately criticize them (and probably also downvote them) and they will be entirely right to do so. Saying "don't criticize this puzzle, it's intentionally unfair" is like saying "don't criticize this food, it intentionally tastes bad" or "don't criticize my arithmetic, I got the answer wrong on purpose".

Comment: (I would prefer Daniel to have been a little less blunt. _Many_ people don't respond well to very direct criticism. But he's not wrong. Cryptic clues are a pretty specific thing, and if you make things that look like cryptic clues but don't follow the rules then unless there's a good reason why they don't then you should expect solvers to be dissatisfied.)

Comment: THIS IS MY SELF DEPRECATION, SO YOU SHOULD DOWNVOTE IT! WHY? BECAUSE IT IS JUST MY FIRST PUZZLE!

Comment: @1357924680a I upvoted it. Been there done that. We all learn and well I had fun solving. I have learnt that cryptic clue tag has many sentiments attached here on puzzling so I have refrained using it. Dont discourage yourself with the comments. Its all fine. Looking forward for more puzzles from you. Cheers :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some of them dont fit cryptic clue rules. But here it goes -

Still, there are wild lionesses (9)

> NOISELESS (still is the def, wild is anagram indicator for lionesses)

David hides in comic RO's sanctuaries (5)

> CROSS (David CROSS) comi**c RO's s**anctuaries which looks more plausible (Thanks @Stiv)

Ocular, said first person (3)

> EYE (ocular is the def, first person I sounds like eye)

Marx's joke with chicken's direction (6)

> HEN+WAY

World's top cartoon company (4)

> ACME

Even shelters scramble, however (12)

> NEVERTHELESS (However def, scramble is the anagram indicator)

A heartless Danish gerund is fleeing (7)

> DA(NI)SH+ING - DASHING ( def fleeing)

Oddly, main dorm in fife, by belly (7)

> MIDRIFF (taking odd letters from Main dorm in fife) def By belly.

Comment: I would have thought the second one more likely to be [this guy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Cross)... (and #5 is a [ddef](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acme))

Comment: @Stiv Hmm.. Yep. That fits as well.

Comment: For 4: rot13(Jung qb 'puvpxra' naq 'qverpgvba' zrna?)

Comment: Also, Numbers 2 and 5 are correct.

Comment: @1357924680a r13(Bhg/Qbja? nf va Puvpxra Bhg?)

Comment: Hint: What else could Marx refer to?

Comment: What weighs about four to six pounds?

Comment: Stiv is right. YOU HAVE DONE IT ALL!

Comment: Top cartoon company (4)
Nick ?