# Cryptic Acrostic 6: Spill the Tea

Tags: cryptic-clues, acrostic

This is an [acrostic puzzle](http://www.puzzazz.com/how-to/acrostics) which uses [cryptic clues](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide). If you're unfamiliar with either or both of those, you can click the associated link.

A complete answer should give the quote, author and source, as well as solutions and explanations of the cryptic clues.

As always, I've created an [interactive version](https://codepen.io/juicifer/full/PoxZqRy) that will autofill from the grid to the clues and vice versa. Have fun!

<sub>An accessible version for the visually impaired can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/LAZESt31).</sub>

[image: an image of the puzzle. for an interactive or accessible version, visit the link above]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quote is:

> "The periodic table is the universal catalog of everything you can drop on your foot. There are some things, such as light, love, logic, and time, that are not in the periodic table. But you can't drop any of those things on your foot."
>
>  — [Theodore Gray](https://libquotes.com/theodore-gray/quote/lbe8a0p), *The Elements*

Answers to the clues:

> A. **Massive** pop? Stretch regularly beforehand. — **TECTONIC** = TONIC (pop) + (s)T(r)E(t)C(h).
>  B. Without leader, Whigs (around midnight) dumped tea from Boston, leading to **subject of July 4 declaration** — **HIGG'S BOSON** = (w)HIG.s around (ni)G(ht) ("midnight") + BOS(t)ON ("dumped tea"), the discovery of Higg's boson was announced on 4 July 2012.
>  C. Maguire's final Wicked book sees half of Oz come to the defenses of Dorothy and **the community at large** — **EVERYBODY** = (maguir)E + VERY ("wicked") + B ("book") + O(z) + D(oroth)Y.
>  D. Tea left out for more time than necessary — **OOLONG** = (t)OO LONG; &lit.: [oolong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oolong) leaves are partially oxidized from being left out in the sun
>  E. **Have misgivings** halfway through getting to second base with partner, essentially — **DOUBT** = **DOUB**(ling) (getting to decond base in baseball, apparently) + (par)T(ner)
>  F. Trap rodent after dropping candy into **antique pot**? — **OUTHOUSE** = (m)OUTH ("trap") + (m)OUSE ("rodent") with m&m, a sweet, cany, missing.
>  G. Source of refreshment - tops in Indian, Chinese economies — **RICE** = R(efreshment) + I(ndian) + C(hinese) + E(conomies), &lit.
>  H. Reader: "Is something the Chinese have often sold to a dictator **what's discussed on page 63 in the book**?" — **EUROPIUM**, sounds like "Your opium". Europium's atomic number is 63.
>  I. **Transfer** tea leaves from jar at the rear of the ship — **GRAFT** = GRA(te + a)FT
>  J. **Location of show on Apple** TV (or Peacock, initially) following Joey Fatone's origin — **ROOFTOP** = ROO ("joey", a little kangaroo) + F(atone) + T(v) + O(r) + P(eacock)
>  K. Dance show without clothing? Very disheartening, and a little fishy — **ANCHOVY** = (d)ANC(e) (s)HO(w) + V(er)Y
>  L. Tampa Bay ballplayer changes direction upon encountering **defensive unit at midfield, for example** — **YARD LINE** = RAY< (a single Tampa Bay Rays player) + D LINE (defensive line)
>  M. Mix two lattes for **someone who talks a lot** — **TATTLETALE** = (LATTE + LATTE)*
>  N. Some watch ouroboros for **the time it takes to complete a circle** — **HOUR** = hidden in ("some") (watc)H OUR(oboros)
>  O. The first nation to obtain a bit of independence in East Africa, ultimately — **ETHIOPIA** = T(he) + I(ndependence) in H.OPI (a native American nation), all inside E + afric(A), &lit.
>  P. English tea - noon-time **delight** — **ENCHANT** = EN (English, ISO abbrev.) + CHA (tea) + N (noon) + T.
>  Q. Maybe blood pressure almost rebounding after Alex slimmed down - ultimately, because **of diet** — **LEGISLATIVE** = (a)LE(x) + VITAL SIG(n)< ("maybe blood pressure almoust rebounding") + (becaus)E; here, the diet is a parliament.
>  R. **One who studies people** of other nations, surprisingly in the region around Hawaii — **ETHNOHISTORIAN** – HI (Hawaii) in (OTHER NATIONS)*
>  S. One wearing retro style? She's fancy, **despite** ... — **MALIGNANCY** = I ("one") inside ("wearing") G.LAM< ("retro style") + Nancy ("she's fancy"). Today I learned that despite is not only a preposition.
>  T. **...** spilling tea over seat, scrubbing last bit of stain — **ET CETERA** = CE(n)TER (last of stain missing from seat) inside TEA*. If you have trouble to make out the bolded portion in the clue, the definition is "...".
>  U. Changing fortunes surrounding a **vampire** — **NOSFERATU** = FORTUNES* around A.
>  V. **Place where you can spend** hours taking breaks in the middle of procrastinating work — **THRIFT SHOP** = H (hours) + RIFTS (breaks) inside (procras)T(inating) + OP (opus, so "work).
>  W. Reserved tour of unusual **base** — **SHODDY** = SHY ("reserved") touring ODD

The title

> I don't think that there is aconnection between the quotation and tea, but tea features in a lot of the clues, as wordplay fodder or as def.

Acknowledgements

> In the comments below, samm82, oAlt and Chris Cudmore gave useful hints to tackle the last missing clues. Do I need to learn more about baseball? Nah, I don't. `:)`

Comment: Beat me to it! I think the word play for L is "LNE<+Q YVAR", but I could be wrong

Comment: Er: R, ["qbhoyr" va gur onfronyy frafr.](https://www.mlb.com/glossary/standard-stats/double) Jvxgvbanel fnlf vg pbhyq nyfb or n ireo, fb qbhoyvat = trggvat gb frpbaq onfr, naq unys bs gung vf qbho. V unira'g shyyl tbggra pyhr V naq Y rvgure, naq va eryngvba gb jung fnzz82 cbvagrq bhg V qba'g xabj jul qrsrafr = Q YVAR. Nf sne nf V xabj vg pna or Q (onfxrgonyy nooeri) ohg V qba'g xabj jurer gur "yvar" jbhyq pbzr sebz

Comment: Oops never mind that last thing I said. I completely misremembered what the clue said. That word wasn't there at all

Comment: Qrsrafvir havg = Q Yvar (Qrsrafvir Yvar)

Comment: Thanks, you three, for your useful input. Sorry to hear I've beaten you, @samm82.

Comment: glad to see you've mostly wrapped everything up. {sbe V: lbh'er irel pybfr gb gur evtug jbeqcynl ohg lbh'er abg dhvgr gurer. V jbhyq'ir vaqvpngrq na nantenz vs bar jnf erdhverq. sbe Y: gung'f npghnyyl zber onfronyy - gur ZYO grnz gurer vf anzrq gur Enlf.} the only other thing is that {V vagraqrq Q gb or na &yvg - bar bs gur cbffvoyr bevtva fgbevrf bs bbybat vf gung [vg jnf nppvqragnyyl yrsg bhg gbb ybat naq fgnegrq gb bkvqvmr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oolong#Possible_origins). lbhe vagrecergngvba vf nyfb inyvq, gubhtu}

Comment: I see. I still don't quite understand how I. works. I suppose we are looking fo a synonym for (a type of) tea here. Anyway, there were so many clever misdirections here, I don't mind not getting the last one ... `:)`

Comment: no, you have all the right components for I. - this was completely unintentional, but you might be able to apply the solution of the clue to help with the wordplay...

Comment: lol, I had BET instead of BUT near the end of the quote, and I was too lazy to double check the correctness of every letter, fml

Comment: Hm, so the first word is doing double duty as def and anagrind?

Comment: @MOehm no anagrams in that clue. to be a bit more explicit, the letters "TEA" are removed in that exact order

Comment: Ah, I get it. ROT 13 Lbh erzbir GRN sebz TENGR NSG -> TEN(-gr n)SG

Comment: @oAlt: Oh, that's very good. I could have stared at this for hours without ever seeing it, although it's obvious in hindsight. Thank you.