# "Idiot" cryptic clue in final episode of "Endeavour"

Tags: cryptic-clues

The final episode of ["Endeavour" Exeunt (TV Episode 2023) - IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt21811792/?ref_=ttep_ep3) made use of this cryptic clue:

> Mother takes murderer back. Idiot.

The answer is:

> Maniac

I understand why that's the answer, but I have no idea what "Idiot" has to do with it.

Comment: I share your frustration. The quick crossword in one UK national daily seems to have two setters who work on alternate days. One of them likes finding angles that are not too obvious, but quite often I'm left thinking ... no, it doesn't actually mean that at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idiot

> is the [*definition* part of the clue](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/45985/57156), being roughly synonymous with Maniac.

For completion,

> "Mother takes murderer back." is the *wordplay* part of the clue yielding **MANIAC** = MA + [CAIN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cain)<

Comment: "roughly synonymous" is a bit too rough for me, but I guess that *was* the intent. Something like "crazy" or "insane" would have fit better.

Comment: The two words you give @RayButterworth are adjectives and don't match the part of speech (noun) of the solution, making them invalid definitions. "Lunatic" would work, though