# Wrecked by three

Tags: knowledge, cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

This is a cryptic crossword. The check mark will go to the first person who submits an answer with 1) an image of the completed crossword and 2) explanations for all clue answers. For users who cannot use Imgur, reproduce the completed crossword through table/code formatting.

[image: wrecked by three grid]

**Across**

> 1. ATM – it's about time that gets fixed in shop (9)
> 6. Piano finale overpowering the sound from the middle of French Louisianian percussion instrument (5)
> 9. Revolutionary monarch and organization beginning to investigate country avoiding tasks (15)
> 10. Risk dropping charge after a month (5)
> 11. Live again in control with husband – slightly touching (9)
> 12. One who arrives holds list of rules in palm (4 2 3)
> 14. Rest of Season 2 episodes featuring Eastern school (5)
> 16. Disagreement: "Man going away *is* part of tradition" (5)
> 18. Complainer's a stone thief, according to Spooner (9)
> 20. *Keratin formation* (a small image) (9)
> 21. "Take place of guard regularly"; there duplicate's planted (5)
> 23. Setter left in New York takes scam at face value without caring about how others feel (15)
> 24. Announcement troubled pet expert (5)
> 25. Restored art, reused and loved (9)

**Down**

> 1. Covers with an edible coating: mostly spicy component (9)
> 2. Scrub an area of tennis court (5)
> 3. Standard ring light released (7)
> 4. Perhaps guitar player with insane talent is in, about to play the strings (15)
> 5. Three people almost wrecked lone route using explosive (15)
> 6. Company hurts teachers (7)
> 7. Can poor baker escape? (9)
> 8. Group of nine being nice try accepting a person (5)
> 13. Tiny particle brings cup closer to a state of chaos (9)
> 15. Flow and exchange of goods and services aurally depicted (9)
> 17. Sandwich and bread share common trait – it's part of a whole (7)
> 19. I like that drinking establishment's lines (7)
> 20. American soldier at revolution in cold forested zone (5)
> 22. Transparent head evicts German at the fastest speed possible (5)

Grid in table form:

|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | 2 |  | 3 |  | 4 |  | 5 | ■ | 6 |  | 7 |  | 8 |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 10 |  |  |  |  | ■ | 11 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ |
| 12 |  | 13 |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 14 |  |  |  | 15 |
|  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 16 |  |  |  | 17 | ■ | 18 |  |  |  | 19 |  |  |  |  |
| ■ | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ | ■ | ■ |  |
| 20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | ■ | 21 |  | 22 |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 23 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  | ■ |  |
| 24 |  |  |  |  | ■ | 25 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

<sub>[Cryptic clue guide by Deusovi](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/45984/cryptic-clue-guide)

[Cryptic crossword on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword)

Grid generated by [Qxw](https://quinapalus.com/qxw.html)</sub>

Comment: Is there a mistake with clue either clue 6 across and 8 down I have found the two clues and it fits too well to deny but the letters don’t overlap?

Comment: While I admit that I haven't checked that far (seeing that no clue has multiple solutions), I confirm that each clue has a solution that shouldn't clash with each other or with other crossing entries.

Comment: @PDT after seeing the solution, what's your 6 across and 8 down?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image: Completed grid]

Clue explanations:

> (Definition parts of cryptic clues in **bold** font.)
>
>  **Across:**
>  1. **ATM** – it's about time that gets fixed in shop (9) **CASHPOINT** = CA. (about, i.e. *circa*) + SHOPIN* + T (time)
>  6. Piano finale overpowering the sound from the middle of [French Louisianian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cajuns) **percussion instrument** (5) **[CAJON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caj%C3%B3n)** = CAJ(u → _O)N
>  9. Revolutionary monarch and organization beginning to investigate country **avoiding tasks** (15) **PROCRASTINATION** = (TSAR + CORP)< + I(-nvestigate) + NATION (country)
>  10. Risk dropping charge after a **month** (5) **APRIL** = A + P(-e)RIL (risk, dropping [charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_charge))
>  11. **Live again in** control with husband – slightly touching (9) **REINHABIT** = REIN (control) + H (husband) + A BIT (slightly)
>  12. One who arrives holds list of rules in **palm** (4 2 3) **[COCO DE MER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legends_of_the_coco_de_mer)** = CODE (list of rules) in COMER (One who arrives)
>  14. **Rest** of Season 2 episodes featuring Eastern school (5) **SLEEP** = S (Season) + (E+EP) (2 episodes) containing (-schoo)L
>  16. Disagreement: "Man going away is **part of tradition**" (5) **NORMS** = NO (Disagreement) + MR< (man, going away) + ‘S (is)
>  18. **Complainer**'s a stone thief, according to Spooner (9) **NITPICKER** = Spooner(PIT NICKER)
>  20. [Keratin formation] [(a small image)] (9) **THUMBNAIL** (ddef)
>  21. "**Take place** of guard regularly"; there duplicate's planted (5) **OCCUR** O’ (of) + _U_R_ containing CC (duplicate, i.e. carbon copy)
>  23. Setter left in New York takes scam at face value **without caring about how others feel** (15) **INCONSIDERATELY** = I (Setter) + N(L)Y (left, in New York) containing (CON (scam) + SIDE (face) + RATE (value))
>  24. Announcement troubled pet **expert** (5) **ADEPT** = AD (Announcement) + PET*
>  25. Restored art, reused and **loved** (9) **TREASURED** = ARTREUSED*
>
>  **Down:**
>  1. Covers with an edible coating: mostly **spicy component** (9) **CAPSAICIN** = CAPS (Covers) + A (an) + ICIN(-g) (edible coating, mostly)
>  2. **Scrub** an area of tennis court (5) **SCOUR** = _S COUR_
>  3. Standard ring light **released** (7) **PAROLED** = PAR (Standard) + O (ring) + LED (light)
>  4. **Perhaps guitar player** with insane talent is in, about to play the strings (15) **INSTRUMENTALIST** = TALENTISIN* containing STRUM (to play the strings)
>  5. Three people almost wrecked lone route using **explosive** (15) **TRINITROTOLUENE** = TRINIT(-y) (Three people, almost) + LONEROUTE*
>  6. Company hurts **teachers** (7) **COACHES** = CO (Company) + ACHES (hurts)
>  7. Can poor baker **escape**? (9) **JAILBREAK** = JAIL (can) + BAKER*
>  8. **Group of nine** being nice try accepting a person (5) **NONET** = NT (nice try) containing ONE (a person)
>  13. **Tiny particle** brings cup closer to a state of chaos (9) **[CORPUSCLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpuscle)** = CUPCLOSER*
>  15. Flow and exchange of goods and services aurally **depicted** (9) **PORTRAYED** = “POUR" (Flow) + "TRADE” (exchange of goods and services)
>  17. Sandwich and bread share common trait – it's **part of a whole** (7) SUB (sandwich) overlapped with BUN (bread) + IT
>  19. I like that drinking establishment's **lines** (7) **ISOBARS** = I + SO (like that) + BAR’S (drinking establishment's)
>  20. American soldier at revolution in **cold forested zone** (5) **TAIGA** = (A (American) + GI (soldier) + AT)<
>  22. **Transparent** head evicts German at the fastest speed possible (5) **CLEAR** = C ([fastest speed possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light)) + LEA(-de)R (head, evicting German)

My personal favourite:

> 23A - using the unit 'face value' to get SIDE and RATE is very nice!

Comment: Well done and thanks :) For 14a, I'm assuming you parsed rot13("frnfba gjb" nf gjb (punenpgref) sebz "frnfba"? Va gung pnfr V qba'g xabj vs rc pna fgnaq sbe rcvfbqrf cyheny. Ohg va nal pnfr V vagraqrq n qvssrerag cnefvat, naq V'yy gel yrnqvat lbh gbjneq vg: vs zl zrzbel freirf V guvax V'ir frra "negvpyrf" pyhvat NA+N orsber, naq urer vg'f n fvzvyne guvat, naq gur "gjb" juvyr cbffvoyl fhcresyhbhf qbrfa'g pbagenqvpg gung...)

Comment: @oAlt Ok I think this revision might now match your intention?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.